# Error setting up jupyter notebook windows on python with pip

Tags: python, pip, installation, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to set up Jupyter on **Windows** with python pip, but I get an error message when I try it.

```
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Samsung\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ta6py17o\pywinpty\
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: try pip install --upgrade setuptools

Comment: It says it's already up-to-date..

Comment: can you check this link? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35991403/pip-install-unroll-python-setup-py-egg-info-failed-with-error-code-1

Comment: Yes I checked it. I tried the things said there, but it didn't work. I tried 'pip install ez_setup', and it seemed to work, but then I got an error while setting up pyzmq.

Comment: what is the error you are getting there?

Comment: The error message is too long. To shorten it, it would be "failed                                                                                                                                   with error code 1 in C:\Users\Samsung\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-sbu4l3qo\py                                                                                                                                  zmq\ "

Comment: which version of Python are you using?

Comment: I'm using Python 3.7.

Comment: Make sure you are using pip3 not pip

Comment: I have the same error and no progress. I have tried the following recommendations from various forums: (a.) upgrade setuptools, (b.) upgrade pip, and (c.) use trusted hosts. No resolution so far!