# Can't install pygame with pip for Python 3.7 - Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1

Tags: python, pip, pygame, installation

I get the below error when trying to install pygame with pip:

```
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in 
C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8zxzuqef\pygame\
```

I don't know what this means, and when i look up in other places to tells me to fix my environment variables. But it still doesn't work.

Comment: How exactly are you trying to install pygame? Which operating system and Python version do you use?

Comment: @skrx Using Windows 10, python 3.7. Aand i'm not sure what you mean by "How exactly are you trying to install pygame" I thought tehre was only method.

Comment: There are different methods.

Comment: @skrx Well I downloaded python, downloaded and installed pip and then did "pip install pygame" and thats how far i got to.

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35991403/pip-install-unroll-python-setup-py-egg-info-failed-with-error-code-1

Comment: @NipunSampath I've been to that exact post before i posted this. Didnt help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update:** [Pygame 1.9.4](https://pypi.org/project/Pygame/1.9.4/) has been released and you can [download and install](https://www.pygame.org/wiki/GettingStarted) it with pip again. In Windows I recommend installing it with: `py -3.7 -m pip install pygame`

---

There are no official precompiled pygame packages for Python 3.7 available yet, so `pip install pygame` doesn't work, but you can get a pygame wheel from: https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pygame

Download `pygame‑1.9.3‑cp37‑cp37m‑win_amd64.whl` if you have a 64-bit Python version or `pygame‑1.9.3‑cp37‑cp37m‑win32.whl` if you have a 32-bit version. Then open the command-line, navigate to the directory that contains the wheel file and install it with pip:

```
py -3.7 -m pip install pygame‑1.9.3‑cp37‑cp37m‑win_amd64.whl
```

---

This solution works only in Windows, so users with other operating systems have to wait and use Python 3.6.

Comment: "Then open the command-line navigate to the directory that contains the wheel file and install it with pip" Not sure how to do this :/

Comment: Enter `cd path_to_the_directory` (replace `path_to_the_directory` with the actual path to your download directory).

Comment: Great! I think it's worked. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

On debian

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pygame
```

works.

Answer (score -2):

Try :

```
py -3.7 -m pip install pygame
```

Comment: Tried This and i get: Requirement already up-to-date: setuptools in c:\users\danie\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (39.2.0) Still no luck after that though.

Comment: I dont know why people gave you dislikes it worked for me as I am having trouble with pip