# Error installing Pygame on Windows through pip

Tags: python, pygame

I am attempting to install Pygame on my computer and keep getting this error.

```
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\admin1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8fv2luo4\Pygame\
```

I have already checked if I have wheels, setuptools and pip and have upgraded all of them. I am running Python 3.7.0.

Here is a screenshot of everything.

[Pygame installation error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MU86i.jpg)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Been Trying to install pygame with pip. Having no luck](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51139635/been-trying-to-install-pygame-with-pip-having-no-luck)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PyGame isn't compatible with Python 3.7.0 (with pip apparently). Downgrade to Python 3.6.x

Comment: @abccd https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51083680/value-error-when-installing-pygame-through-pycharm?noredirect=1#comment89160323_51083680

Answer (score 0):

Pygame is actually compatible with Python 3.7. You will just need to uninstall the old version for 3.6 and download the new wheel file for 3.7.