# Problems setting up pygame for python 3.7.0 for mac

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, pygame

I have been trying to get pygame to work with python 3.7.0 on my mac with OS High Sierra (version 10.13.4), and have been browsing for solutions on how to do this for a few days now, but have had no luck in actually getting it to work.

These are some of the more helpful ones I have tried to follow:
http://brysonpayne.com/2015/01/10/setting-up-pygame-on-a-mac/
https://gist.github.com/exPHAT/0cfc67ceb8982d11fd27

I have gotten to the point by which I can enter the terminal command to download it for python 3, and it starts to download, but then outputs the errors:

***Failed building wheel for pygame***

and followed shortly after by the end error:

> *Command "/usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.7 -u -c "import setuptools,
>   tokenize;**file**='/private/var/folders/3c/yxl262h179q0_5shjw3d0xk80000gn/T/pip-req-build-v8qcr3mi/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize,
>   'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n',
>   '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install
>   --record /private/var/folders/3c/yxl262h179q0_5shjw3d0xk80000gn/T/pip-record-ep1ffaia/install-record.txt
>   --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in
>   /private/var/folders/3c/yxl262h179q0_5shjw3d0xk80000gn/T/pip-req-build-v8qcr3mi/*

I do not know why this is and have tried numerous methods to resolve this but none have worked. I would greatly appreciate any help with this problem as I have spent a very long time trying to get it to work and am eager to start programming with pygame.

NOTE: I am aware that mercurial does not fully support python 3.x and have gotten pygame to work on python 2.x, so am thinking the problem might be to do with mercurial, but am not sure.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51159514/6220679  Try Python 3.6.

Comment: Maybe just stick with Python 3.6 for now?

Comment: I tried using the python 3.6.6 version by installing it from the python website instead of via terminal, and then followed this tutorial to download it: https://gist.github.com/exPHAT/0cfc67ceb8982d11fd27 I had to duplicate the python 3.6 version from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/versions and add the duplicated version to /usr/local/Cellar/python3 (I made a new folder called python3 and added the duplicated version to it) and it worked! Thank you for the suggestions!