# Installing pygame 1.9.3 on python 3.7, mac high sierra

Tags: python, pygame

need some help!

Trying to install Pygame on a mac 10.13.5 high sierra using the terminal command
 'python3 -m pip install Pygame==1.9.3'

Python is version 3.7
pip is version 10.0.1

Error in terminal:

error: command ‘gcc’ failed with exit status 1

Command “/usr/local/bin/python3 -u -c “import setuptools, tokenize;**file**=’/private/var/folders/yw/7rmtmwzn6s37g28zr1b8mnww0000gn/T/pip-install-8vxx887g/Pygame/setup.py’;f=getattr(tokenize, ‘open’, open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace(‘\r\n’, ‘\n’);f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, ‘exec’))” install –record /private/var/folders/yw/7rmtmwzn6s37g28zr1b8mnww0000gn/T/pip-record-_h7yuqzv/install-record.txt –single-version-externally-managed –compile” failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/yw/7rmtmwzn6s37g28zr1b8mnww0000gn/T/pip-install-8vxx887g/Pygame/

I've tried searching for an answer but can't get it to work, any help would be much appreciated

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51159514/6220679 Use Python 3.6.

Comment: Ah! Thanks a million! Installed python 3.6 instead and it works! Golden!