# How can I successfully install pygame into python3 on Mac? I tried a lot of syntaxes to download pygame in python3. But none of them worked

Tags: python-3.x, macos, pygame

I had successfully installed pygame in python2 using pip on Mac. But I was unable to install pygame in python3.

After entering the following commands:

```
$ brew install hg sol sdl_image sdl_ttf
$ brew install sdl_mixer portmidi
$ pip3 install --user hg_http://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame
```

I got:

```
Failed building wheel for pygame
  Running setup.py clean for pygame
Failed to build pygame
Installing collected packages: pygame
  Running setup.py install for pygame ... error
```

And:

```
36 warnings and 8 errors generated.
    error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1
```

I had ensured that I installed wheel and the newest version of setuptools. I tried again using the command:

```
$ pip3 install pygame
```

I still got:

```
Failed building wheel for pygame
  Running setup.py clean for pygame
Failed to build pygame
Installing collected packages: pygame
  Running setup.py install for pygame ... error
```

Other syntaxes I had tried:

```
$ pip3 install Pygame==1.9.3
$ python3 -m pip install pygame
```

But all of them generated the same error.

So, how can I successfully install pygame in python3?

Comment: Which Python version?

Comment: Python 3.7.0 version

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pip install pygame on ubuntu 18.04 using pyenv/python 3.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51159099/pip-install-pygame-on-ubuntu-18-04-using-pyenv-python-3-7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use pip 
just enter

```
    python3 -m pip install pygame
```

Here is a link that can be helpful

http://medium.com/@louiscouture/tl-dr-pip-bcddaca44540
You basically used the wrong syntax for pip.

Comment: Thanks, but this syntax also generated the same error for me.

Comment: Also, I can't view the link

Comment: Oh wait. You use python 3.7? I don’t think that is possible because python 3.7 is not the official version. Beside pygame hasn’t been updated since January 2017. You need to download another version of python on python.org