# How to understand this Pygame error?

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7

I'm trying to install Pygame on My computer. I am running Mac OSX with Python 3.7.0. I successfully installed pip3, but when I try to install Pygame using `sudo pip3 install hg+http://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame`, I get the following error:

```
Command "/usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.7 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/tmp/pip-install-arxkd3yz/pygame/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /private/tmp/pip-record-iq00o_g3/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-install-arxkd3yz/pygame/
```

What is the reason for this error, and a fix for the same?

Comment: Why not just `sudo pip3 install pygame`? From the bitbucket repo, I see they have moved to [github](https://github.com/pygame/pygame/).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I successfully install pygame into python3 on Mac? I tried a lot of syntaxes to try download pygame in python3. But none of them worked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51391690/how-can-i-successfully-install-pygame-into-python3-on-mac-i-tried-a-lot-of-synt)