# Can't download pygame with pip on windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, pygame

Keep running into this issue trying to download pygame. How do i download it with pip? I use a 64bit windows 10 w/ python 3.7... Thanks

```
C:\Users\Antoine>python -m pip install -U pygame --user
Collecting pygame
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/61/06/3c25051549c252cc6fde01c8aeae90b96831370884504fe428a623316def/pygame-1.9.3.tar.gz
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:


WARNING, No "Setup" File Exists, Running "config.py"
Using WINDOWS configuration...

Path for SDL not found.
Too bad that is a requirement! Hand-fix the "Setup"
Path for FONT not found.
Path for IMAGE not found.
Path for MIXER not found.
Path for PNG not found.
Path for JPEG not found.
Path for PORTMIDI not found.
Path for COPYLIB_tiff not found.
Path for COPYLIB_z not found.
Path for COPYLIB_vorbis not found.
Path for COPYLIB_ogg not found.

If you get compiler errors during install, doublecheck
the compiler flags in the "Setup" file.


Continuing With "setup.py"
Error with the "Setup" file,
perhaps make a clean copy from "Setup.in".
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Antoine\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-0c2lpkkq\pygame\setup.py", line 165, in <module>
    extensions = read_setup_file('Setup')
  File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\distutils\extension.py", line 171, in read_setup_file
    line = expand_makefile_vars(line, vars)
  File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\distutils\sysconfig.py", line 407, in expand_makefile_vars
    s = s[0:beg] + vars.get(m.group(1)) + s[end:]
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str
```

Comment: Which python are you using ?

Comment: He says he's using 3.7 and it's in the traceback.

Comment: `pip install setuptools` then try again

Comment: @nosklo Thanks I have setup tools (40.0.0) installed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't install pygame with pip for Python 3.7 - Command "python setup.py egg\_info" failed with error code 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51139635/cant-install-pygame-with-pip-for-python-3-7-command-python-setup-py-egg-info)

Comment: [Pygame 1.9.4](https://pypi.org/project/Pygame/1.9.4/) has been released and you can [download and install](https://www.pygame.org/wiki/GettingStarted) it with pip again.

Answer (score 0):

Pygame doesn't install properly in 3.7. Install 3.6.6 instead. I had the same problem