# pip install presto : Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1

Tags: python, pip, installation, macos-high-sierra

Im trying to install presto on an iMac with High Sierra. I followed every step in this [guide](http://presto.readthedocs.io/en/version-0.5.7---maskprimers-extract/install.html) but at the last step `> pip3 install presto` I get following error:

"Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/m2/1tsgrfm16rv0d42lsdmzw9b40000gr/T/pip-install-a6tq2cq4/presto/
Ladmins-iMac:~ patrick$ "

I installed python with homebrew and everything is up to date.
I already tried everything mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35991403/pip-install-unroll-python-setup-py-egg-info-failed-with-error-code-1/36025294#36025294) but nothing seems to work for me.There were no problems installing other packages like pandas, numpy and scipy.
Would gladly appreciate your help!

Comment: I just want to make sure, did you follow instruction for MAC OS [here](https://pypi.org/project/presto/) ?

Comment: Yes I followed the instructions in the Mac OS section.

Comment: Please post the full error trace.

Comment: I got in touch with the developer and apperently the current version of presto does not work with the new version of pip.