# "sudo pip install chaco" failed with error

Tags: python, installation

```
sudo pip install chaco
```

I got the following error while installing the `chaco`

**edit**

```
numpy.distutils.system_info.X11NotFoundError: X11 libraries not found.
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-io68CQ/enable/
```

I couldn't find the same error by googling.

What is the solution?

Regards,

As @jdowner suggested I tried to install prerequisite package `enable`

```
sudo pip install enable
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-DtvVEq/enable/
```

libx11-dev installed. 
I do have all the requirement of `enable`.

The error after installing  x11 is:

```
sudo pip install chaco

Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-Tf5jwE/enable/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-eM7Q_l/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-Tf5jwE/enable/
```

Comment: It means that there are missing dependencies. https://github.com/enthought/chaco contains a list of required dependencies at the bottom of the readme.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["pip install unroll": "python setup.py egg\_info" failed with error code 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35991403/pip-install-unroll-python-setup-py-egg-info-failed-with-error-code-1)

Comment: No I already saw that post.

Comment: Look at the prerequisites section: https://github.com/enthought/enable Do you have all of those installed?