# Is there a way to use processing with the python shell?

Tags: python, pip, processing

I'd like to know if ther's a way to use the visual framework processing (https://py.processing.org) with the original python shell, like to import it as a module, as I've seen in a french school's python-teaching page.
I've tried 'pip install processing' but get the following error:

' Command"python setup.py egg_info" failed with error 1 in C:\ ... \Temp\pip-install-pdk9ihlb\processing\ '

I've already searched for solutions to that particular error but all solutions that worked for others I've tried did not resolve my problem. Although, I didn't find any .whl file for processing, and I've seen people resolving the error I got by installing via a created-by-themselves whl file (but I have no idea how to do it).

If anyone knows anything on the subject of processing, resolving pip errors or creating a wheel file, please feel free to help a newcomer like me. Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide more information. Which version of python, which operating system, and what solutions you have already tried.
Also is there anything relevant about your setup, the version of pip perhaps, whether you are trying to install processing into a virtualenv?
Further, your question is tagged processing, the tag describes the educational visual framework, the pip package is a multi-threading library. Which are you trying to use?
https://py.processing.org/tutorials/gettingstarted/
https://pypi.org/project/processing/

Comment: seems like I was too happy about the module being able to be pip-ed that I didn't even read that much, didn't see it was something else. I'm trying to use the educational visual framework, and my question still holds, is it possible to use it in the python shell without using the distributed program? I'm using python 3.7.2 on Windows 7 64 with IdleX, and the latest version of pip as I updated it trying to figure out how to install the processing module.

Comment: I've already tried quite a lot of the solutions provided in this question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35991403/pip-install-unroll-python-setup-py-egg-info-failed-with-error-code-1) but none of those mentionning any sudo command, as cmd doesn't let me use it and don't know how to properly use it (told you I was a newcomer).

Comment: I don't have the answer, after a quick search I can't find processing in pypi, so pip install is not going to get you what you want.
I don't know enough about processing to know what you're trying to achieve, we'll need someone with more expertise. In light of this perhaps you could update your question to better explain your first sentence, perhaps provide an example.
I assume you've read https://py.processing.org/tutorials/gettingstarted/ and https://py.processing.org/tutorials/overview/

Comment: I did read those and everything that seemed to work but none lead to success. I'll document myself on the subject and perhaps I'll be able to add precisions on the topic and find a solution, Thanks for your time.