# Error: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed

Tags: python, airflow

I am trying to install airflow in mac using the command

```
pip install apache-airflow
```

getting error

> "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in 
>       /private/var/folders/pn/15z8bhh90qx35641zsk82y0c0000gn/T/pip-install- 
>        wvo1m1bl/apache-airflow/

I have upgraded pip using `pip install unroll` but it is not helping. Have also done `easy_install -U setuptools`. Anyone have faced similar error,  please share your views.

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/36025294/7796098 to see whether it is helpful

Answer (score 2):

I think you have python3 installed. try to install airflow using

```
sudo pip3 install apache-airflow
```

There is a python package manager call [anaconda](https://anaconda.org/). Is you install it, You would install the airflow using `conda install -c conda-forge airflow`

Comment: 0


I have tried using python 3 too but it is still throwing error as below Collecting apache-

**Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-install-7zuvz4ig/apache-airflow/ **