# Unable to install pyautogui through pip install with error1

Tags: python, windows, pip, pyautogui

I'm trying to install pyautogui through code 'pip install pyautogui'
But the program always give me an error like following 
I started Visual Studio Code with Administration Authority

=========================================================================================

```
(.venv) C:\Users\USer\Desktop\pythoncode>pip install pyautogui
Collecting pyautogui
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/19/ef/438d80abd396fd2d124bd37c07c765f913723c54197c4c809d85c8ff5a43/PyAutoGUI-0.9.41.tar.gz
Collecting pymsgbox (from pyautogui)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b6/65/86379ede1db26c40e7972d7a41c69cdf12cc6a0f143749aabf67ab8a41a1/PyMsgBox-1.0.6.zip
Collecting PyTweening>=1.0.1 (from pyautogui)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b9/f8/c32a58d6e4dff8aa5c27e907194d69f3b57e525c2e4af96f39c6e9c854d2/PyTweening-1.0.3.zip
Requirement already satisfied: Pillow in c:\users\user\desktop\pythoncode\.venv\lib\site-packages (from pyautogui) (5.4.1)
Collecting pyscreeze (from pyautogui)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f3/27/073bf07400943e38b06ba40def60ec489d114fd7356c2db5a2f793454312/PyScreeze-0.1.19.tar.gz
Collecting pygetwindow (from pyautogui)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/01/ed/56d4a369c6e18f6b239d9ef37b3222ba308bfebf949571b2611ff7d64f1d/PyGetWindow-0.0.4.tar.gz
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\USer\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-wupkdbtd\pygetwindow\setup.py", line 11, in <module>
    long_description = fh.read()
UnicodeDecodeError: 'cp949' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 903: illegal multibyte sequence

----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\USer\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-wupkdbtd\pygetwindow\
```

=========================================================================================

I use 32bit windows  and 32bit python 3.7

I already upgrade my pip with code `pip install --upgrade pip`.(current version is 19.0.2 now)

And I have tried a prompt with administration authority and type `pip install pyautogui` but Prompt also gave me the same error :

```
Command "python seup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\USer\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-e2r19eza\pygetwindow\
```

I already try the solution that the follwing link suggets but I failed
["pip install unroll": "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35991403/pip-install-unroll-python-setup-py-egg-info-failed-with-error-code-17) 
I failed to do `easy_install -U setuptools` with an error:

```
WinError 5] Access is denied :  'c:\\users\\user\\desktop\\pythoncode\\.venv\\Scripts\\easy_install.exe'
```

Please share your wisdom to the beginner

Comment: Can you please try doing easy_install pillow first and then pip install pyautogui

Answer (score 2):

Try to install as an Administrator.

```
pip install pyautogui
```