# Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-qrebbk1j\cffi\

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy, pip

Please read before marking as duplicate:
I am trying to install scrapy with pip but it gives me following error:

> Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-qrebbk1j\cffi\

I have tried every solution available on stackoverflow and nothing solves my error.
Yes,my pip is updated and setup_tools is also updated.
Everything was working fine and I did install other packages today itself but when I tried to install scrapy it gave this error and I have no idea what else i can do I tried everything I could do.
[I followed every step on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35991403/pip-install-unroll-python-setup-py-egg-info-failed-with-error-code-1)
However, nothing works, please help.

Comment: when i simply install scrapy it gives above mentioned errors and when I updated things mentioned in answer they all were updated successfully and whenever I tried to install scrapy it gave the same error in every method.

Comment: I see that you're trying to install a package to a local version of python. The problem here seems to be a permission problem. Would you consider pyenv to manage python environments? Also, try to run the command line as administrator.

Comment: I did what you suggested and now I am getting different error. error: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SDKs\\Windows\\v8.1\\lib'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally resolved the issue, as it happens the package I was trying to install needs windows sdk 8.1 which got installed after installing the sdk.

However now this also installs a package called twisted for dependency I guess, which has some components written in C thus it needs a C compiler. which gave me this error

> error: Setup script exited with error: command 'cl.exe' failed: No such file or directory

Hence, I could download a vs c++ compiler and it would solve the error. But a simpler solution would be downloading an already compiled version of the required packages which are mostly available on [this site](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#distribute) for windows. Although this is not official distribution so use it at your own risk.