# Windows - Unable to Install pyautogui through pip - ERROR: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1

Tags: python, pip, pyautogui

I'm installing python package ***pyautogui*** through pip, like below:

```
pip install pyautogui
```

However, it shows the error:

```
    ERROR: Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    ERROR: Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\Winnie\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-dxvr5jhi\pygetwindow\setup.py", line 11, in <module>
        long_description = fh.read()
    UnicodeDecodeError: 'cp950' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 903: illegal multibyte sequence
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Winnie\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-dxvr5jhi\pygetwindow\
```

I've search my problem on the stackoverflow, and I did the same way as ["pip install unroll": "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35991403/pip-install-unroll-python-setup-py-egg-info-failed-with-error-code-1)

When I tried `easy_install -U setuptools`

It shows:

```
error: [WinError 5] Permission denied: 'c:\\users\\winnie\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python37-32\\Scripts\\easy_install.exe'
```

Here is what I'm using:

- OS: Windows 10
- python: 3.7.3
- pip: 19.1

What's wrong with my computer? Can anyone help me?
Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Can you please run the commands using Admin role.
**pip install pyautogui**

Answer (score 0):

Find the link above those ERROR messages :

Collecting pygetwindow (from pyautogui)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/01/ed/56d4a369c6e18f6b239d9ef37b3222ba308bfebf949571b2611ff7d64f1d/PyGetWindow-0.0.4.tar.gz
ERROR......

Download it and edit "setup.py":

...
    # Load version from module (without loading the whole module)
    with open('src/pygetwindow/**init**.py', 'r',**encoding="UTF-8"**) as fd:
        version = re.search(r'^**version**\s*=\s*\'"[\'"]',
                            fd.read(), re.MULTILINE).group(1)
    # Read in the README.md for the long description.
    with open("README.md", "r",**encoding="UTF-8"**) as fh:
        long_description = fh.read()
...

Add encoding="UTF-8" into the **open** function arg

Re-archive the tar file, run pip install PyGetWindow-0.0.4.tar

Finally run again pip install pyautogui