# gcloud app deploy fails on 'Running setup.py install for appscript'

Tags: python, google-app-engine

When running the command `cloud app deploy` in the command line, it fails on installing requirements.txt after it hits "Running setup.py install for appscript: started".

```
Command "/env/bin/python3.6 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-18grw9xa/appscript/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-vm76fdr2/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /env/include/site/python3.6/appscript" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-18grw9xa/appscript/
Step #1: You are using pip version 10.0.1, however version 19.2.2 is available.
Step #1: You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
Step #1: The command '/bin/sh -c pip install -r requirements.txt' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you need to upgrade your pip. Take a look here [Failed with error code 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35991403/pip-install-unroll-python-setup-py-egg-info-failed-with-error-code-1) to try to do it. It must works for you.