# Unable to download InstaPy python module via pip install

Tags: python, python-3.x, instagram

This error comes up when trying to install InstaPy python module:

---

Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/eb/ee/e59e74ecac678a14d6abefb9054f0bbcb318a6452a30df3776f133886d7d/
googleapis-common-protos-1.6.0.tar.gz
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\Seyi\Python\Python36\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; 
sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\Seyi\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-i7zyc4ej
\googleapis-common-protos\setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'C:\Users\Seyi\AppData\Local\Temp\
pip-install-i7zyc4ej\googleapis-common-protos\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)
(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))
' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\Seyi\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-i7zyc4ej\googleapis-common-protos\pip-egg-info'
         cwd: C:\Users\Seyi\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-i7zyc4ej\googleapis-common-protos\
    Complete output (21 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "", line 1, in 
      File "C:\Users\Seyi\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\setuptools__init__.py", line 10, in 
        from setuptools.extern.six.moves import filter, filterfalse, map
      File "C:\Users\Seyi\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\setuptools\extern__init__.py", line 1, in 
        from pkg_resources.extern import VendorImporter
      File "C:\Users\Seyi\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources__init__.py", line 3017, in 
        @_call_aside
      File "C:\Users\Seyi\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources__init__.py", line 3003, in _call_aside
        f(*args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\Seyi\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources__init__.py", line 3045, in _initialize_master_working_set
        dist.activate(replace=False)
      File "C:\Users\Seyi\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources__init__.py", line 2577, in activate
        declare_namespace(pkg)
      File "C:\Users\Seyi\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources__init__.py", line 2151, in declare_namespace
        _handle_ns(packageName, path_item)
      File "C:\Users\Seyi\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources__init__.py", line 2091, in _handle_ns
        _rebuild_mod_path(path, packageName, module)
      File "C:\Users\Seyi\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources__init__.py", line 2120, in _rebuild_mod_path
        orig_path.sort(key=position_in_sys_path)
    AttributeError: '_NamespacePath' object has no attribute 'sort'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.

Answer (score 0):

Please mention the command that you are using. However, I would suggest you to update pip, and make sure to use pip3 if applicable.

Comment: I typed : python -m pip install instapy

Answer (score 0):

It seems my setuptools wasn't up to date so I had to upgrade it via pip.

Command line used: python -m pip install --upgrade setuptools
(You probably won't need the python part)

Full explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35991403/pip-install-unroll-python-setup-py-egg-info-failed-with-error-code-1)