# Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-j2idi2/scikit-learn/

Tags: amazon-ec2, installation, scikit-learn

I got this error when I tried to install sklearn when launching AWS EC2 instance.I tried looking for ways but
I couldn't understand what I should do .

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["pip install unroll": "python setup.py egg\_info" failed with error code 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35991403/pip-install-unroll-python-setup-py-egg-info-failed-with-error-code-1)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`pip3 install --upgrade setuptools`

`pip3 install --upgrade pip`

(you might have to navigate back to the original/root folder)

ref: https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/whatever/python+setup.py+egg_info%22+failed+with+error+code+1+i