# error while installing pywhatkit in ubnutu

Tags: python, installation, pip

when i run `pip install pywhatkit` i get an error like this . am using ubuntu 18.04

```
 Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/1a/98/4c3b22d090d255cfe9c407459e4c05e86ae4a22aab0e410f6d75a5f73b98/pywhatkit-5.3.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-JbDlBk/pywhatkit/setup.py", line 6
        def readme() -> str:
                     ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
    
    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-JbDlBk/pywhatkit/
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35991403/pip-install-unroll-python-setup-py-egg-info-failed-with-error-code-1) help?