# Numpy Install RuntimeError: Broken toolchain: cannot link a simple C program

Tags: python, numpy, homebrew

(macbook air)

I spent a while trying to install this. First off, I can't use Homebrew because I installed it but then the 'network connection' dropped and now my computer can't find the 'brew' command, but it says homebrew  in installed. So I don't know how to uninstall it without using the brew command.

So I am trying to install numpy from the command line. I have xcode, command line tools, gcc fortran 4.2.3, and downloaded numpy. I am getting a RuntimeError when trying to install it! I've read and tried everything from previous posts.

I have attached my Path to show you all, maybe I messed that up?

```
 echo $PATH
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4 bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

Would love your help!!

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 251, in <module>
    setup_package()
  File "setup.py", line 243, in setup_package
    setup(**metadata)
  File "/Users/Anisa/Downloads/numpy-1.9.1/numpy/distutils/core.py", line 169, in setup
    return old_setup(**new_attr)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/distutils/core.py", line 152, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/distutils/dist.py", line 975, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/distutils/dist.py", line 995, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/Users/Anisa/Downloads/numpy-1.9.1/numpy/distutils/command/build.py", line 39, in run
    old_build.run(self)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/distutils/command/build.py", line 134, in run
    self.run_command(cmd_name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/distutils/cmd.py", line 333, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/distutils/dist.py", line 995, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/Users/Anisa/Downloads/numpy-1.9.1/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 153, in run
    self.build_sources()
  File "/Users/Anisa/Downloads/numpy-1.9.1/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 164, in build_sources
    self.build_library_sources(*libname_info)
  File "/Users/Anisa/Downloads/numpy-1.9.1/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 299, in build_library_sources
    sources = self.generate_sources(sources, (lib_name, build_info))
  File "/Users/Anisa/Downloads/numpy-1.9.1/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 386, in generate_sources
    source = func(extension, build_dir)
  File "numpy/core/setup.py", line 686, in get_mathlib_info
    raise RuntimeError("Broken toolchain: cannot link a simple C program")
RuntimeError: Broken toolchain: cannot link a simple C program
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Problems with pip install numpy - RuntimeError: Broken toolchain: cannot link a simple C program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22388519/problems-with-pip-install-numpy-runtimeerror-broken-toolchain-cannot-link-a)

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this issue twice, and both times I fixed it this way: abandoning pip.

First time was on osx I did `brew install numpy`. Homebrew will take care of all of the dependencies.

Second time was on centos7 and much like above I just `yum install -y numpy`.

Comment: I think you're supposed to use something called Virtual Environment to install numpy. I've been using matlab but I'll try virtual environment and let you all know.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with Python3 numpy install in Fedora 24

Solution provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37145552/6657370) by Ollegn that worked for me was:

```
sudo dnf install python3-devel
sudo dnf install make automake gcc gcc-c++ gcc-gfortran
sudo dnf install redhat-rpm-config
sudo dnf install subversion
sudo pip3 install -U numpy
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm having this same problem (only I'm using `brew install numpy`), with:

```
File "numpy/core/setup.py", line 686, in get_mathlib_info
    raise RuntimeError("Broken toolchain: cannot link a simple C program")
RuntimeError: Broken toolchain: cannot link a simple C program
```

([Here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/cea900b450469bb5b0ca) is a full `gist-log` of my `error`.)

This question has some potential solutions:  [Problems with pip install numpy - RuntimeError: Broken toolchain: cannot link a simple C program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22388519/problems-with-pip-install-numpy-runtimeerror-broken-toolchain-cannot-link-a).

Though I don't want to resort to `sudo`, and I want to stick with `homebrew` (because I'm really aiming for a homebrewed `opencv`), so I've had no luck so far.

Edit: adding `export ARCHFLAGS=-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future` to my `.bash_profile` (as was suggested in the other question I linked) let brew install `numpy` *almost* flawlessly. All that remained after was that I had to `brew link --overwrite numpy` (because I had a non-brew installation of numpy before). Seems to be working now.

Comment: Thanks! I had to combine two solutions to install numpy under homebrew pypy (4.0.1) on OS X (el capitan): 1. don't use pip ot get numpy, but get it from github: `pypy -m pip install git+https://bitbucket.org/pypy/numpy.git@pypy-4.0.1` and using the `export` mentioned in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

update the pip using   python -m pip install --upgrade pip

then install your library     pip install your_library