# Install libssl-dev for Docker

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm building an image for Docker and it's giving me error:

```
ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:
libssl-dev (missing):
required by: world[libssl-dev]
```

running `RUN apk add libssl-dev` doesn't seem to help.
What can I do to resolve this ?

Dockerfile-dev:

```
FROM python:3.6.7-alpine

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY ./requirements.txt /usr/src/app/requirements.txt
RUN apk add libssl-dev
RUN apk add libffi-dev
RUN apk add --update python3 python3-dev py-pip build-base
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

COPY . /usr/src/app

CMD python3 manage.py run -h 0.0.0.0
```

Comment: Can you post your entire Dockerfile?

Comment: Why did you decide that the name of the package is `libssl-dev`? It looks like it is a dev package for openssl in Debian-based distros (https://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/amd64/libssl-dev/filelist), and in Alpine it is `openssl-dev` (https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/contents?file=&path=&name=openssl-dev&branch=edge&repo=main&arch=x86_64).

Answer (score 42):

Some packages are built against `libressl` in Alpine 3.6. Try replacing line 6 in your Dockerfile with the following

```
RUN apk add libressl-dev
```

Comment: `libressl-dev` does not seem to work for all settings. With an outdated postgreSQL alpine image I get `ERROR: Service 'xyz' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c apk add libressl-dev' returned a non-zero code: 2`.

Answer (score 2):

I am just a beginner at apk packages and their dependency conflicts. No guarantees for anything, I just hope it helps someone.

From [LibreSSL](https://www.libressl.org/):

> LibreSSL is a version of the TLS/crypto stack forked from OpenSSL in 2014, with goals of modernizing the codebase, improving security, and applying best practice development processes.

Both `openssl-dev` and `libressl-dev` depend on `libssl`. If you install one of the two, you will probably install `libssl-dev` with it. At least, after running (taken from https://github.com/gliderlabs/docker-alpine/issues/297):

```
RUN apk add gcc musl-dev python3-dev libffi-dev openssl-dev
```

I got this conflict by running (taken from [Installing pandas in docker Alpine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54890328/installing-pandas-in-docker-alpine), probably not necessary in my case anyway):

```
RUN apk add postgresql-dev libxml2 libxml2-dev libxslt libxslt-dev libjpeg-turbo-dev zlib-dev
```

Which outputs:

```
ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:
  openssl-dev-1.0.2t-r0:
    conflicts:
               libressl-dev-2.6.5-r0[pc:libcrypto=1.0.2t]
               libressl-dev-2.6.5-r0[pc:libssl=1.0.2t]
               libressl-dev-2.6.5-r0[pc:openssl=1.0.2t]
    satisfies: world[openssl-dev]
  libressl-dev-2.6.5-r0:
    conflicts:
               openssl-dev-1.0.2t-r0[pc:libcrypto=2.6.5]
               openssl-dev-1.0.2t-r0[pc:libssl=2.6.5]
               openssl-dev-1.0.2t-r0[pc:openssl=2.6.5]
    satisfies:
               postgresql-dev-10.10-r0[libressl-dev]
```

We see that the conflict is caused by installing openssl-dev and postgresql-dev.

In this case, it seems that this version of `openssl` has younger dependencies since the seemingly newer `openssl-dev-1.0.2t-r0` (latest version seems to be `1.1.1` in 8/2021, see [OpenSSL](https://www.openssl.org/)) conflicts with the older `libssl=1.0.2t` while the older `libressl-dev-2.6.5-r0` (latest version is already `3.4` in 8/2021) conflicts with the younger `libssl=2.6.5`.

From all this, I read that `libssl` gets installed as a dependency by `openssl-dev` or `libressl-dev`, the latter of which seems to be installed for example by packages like `postgresql-dev`.