# Docker multistage build, python and java

Tags: pandas, docker, alpine-linux

I'm trying to use https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/

I need openjdk 8 and latest panda on alpine 
(I'm installing spark / pyspark)

I initially tried using `FROM openjdk:8-alpine` and then installing all python3 / pandas , but it turns out installing pandas is rather hard in alpine and you need latest alpine docker image ([Installing pandas in docker Alpine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54890328/installing-pandas-in-docker-alpine))

So I need `FROM openjdk:8-alpine`  and `From alpine:latest`

My question is how do I know which directory(?) to copy from the each step?

If I do

```
FROM openjdk:8-alpine
From alpine:latest
```

I'll need copy java8 related stuff from the `openjdk:8-alpine`

If I do reverse

```
From alpine:latest
# install panda 
FROM openjdk:8-alpine
```

I'll need copy (what??)

Comment: I think you need to install JDK manually on the image , multistage will not be helpfull in your case

Comment: This should help: https://pythonspeed.com/articles/multi-stage-docker-python/

Comment: BTW, even if you are able to copy all the libraries of python/pandas in the `openjdk:8-alpine` how would you use them? They would still require `python` binary in the final image, right?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you need both in the same image?  Typical practice if you have two application components in separate programs is to run them in two separate containers, and use a network call (like HTTP) between them.

Comment: I need to run spark (which requires java) and pyspark which is python.. I guess I could separate them but probably easier to setup single docker.. @DavidMaze

Comment: @eugene A general rule is to run only one application per container, even if they're on the same stack (eg: both java apps).
It is possible to run multiple application on one container but that too has complexities. See https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/multi-service_container/

Comment: @Bernard thanks for the tip, I'll take that into account, but I doubt you can separate java /python in spark / pyspark app. (top google hits for spark docker file example have java/python in one dockerfile such as https://github.com/Fokko/docker-pyspark/blob/master/Dockerfile)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use multi-stage build, you typically create an artefact (a compiled app for instance) during the first phase, and copy it to a slimmer base image on the second phase. Everything from the first stage is discarded when the final image is created.

From your comments, I think I understand that you need to start from an image that has both JDK8 AND the latest alpine. Multi-stage build doesn't help here. You'd end up just copying the JDK to the alpine:latest final stage.

I would instead copy the original Dockerfile [jdk:8-alpine](https://github.com/docker-library/openjdk/blob/dd54ae37bc44d19ecb5be702d36d664fed2c68e4/8/jdk/alpine/Dockerfile), change the first line to `FROM alpine:3.10` and create your own base image.

If you need pyspark based on this image, you copy the [original dockerfile](https://github.com/Fokko/docker-pyspark/blob/master/Dockerfile) and replace the first line `FROM openjdk:8` with your base image created previously.