# Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully (running Docker)

Tags: pandas, docker, flask, alpine-linux

I've been trying to run `docker build -t flask-container` so that I can upload my flask webapp to AWS.

However, when trying to run this, pyproject.toml ends with an error.

```
installing build dependencies: started
6.575   Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
6.575   Getting requirements to build wheel: started
6.635   Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
6.641   Installing backend dependencies: started
7.182   Installing backend dependencies: finished with status 'done'
7.183   Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): started
7.498   Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'
7.500   error: subprocess-exited-with-error
7.500   
7.500   × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
7.500   │ exit code: 1
7.500   ╰─> [20 lines of output]
7.500       + meson setup /tmp/pip-install-k7rku_2t/pandas_873652e11bdc4d6295d70d48e70c056e /tmp/pip-install-k7rku_2t/pandas_873652e11bdc4d6295d70d48e70c056e/.mesonpy-304oy531/build -Dbuildtype=release -Db_ndebug=if-release -Db_vscrt=md --vsenv --native-file=/tmp/pip-install-k7rku_2t/pandas_873652e11bdc4d6295d70d48e70c056e/.mesonpy-304oy531/build/meson-python-native-file.ini
7.500       The Meson build system
7.500       Version: 1.2.1
7.500       Source dir: /tmp/pip-install-k7rku_2t/pandas_873652e11bdc4d6295d70d48e70c056e
7.500       Build dir: /tmp/pip-install-k7rku_2t/pandas_873652e11bdc4d6295d70d48e70c056e/.mesonpy-304oy531/build
7.500       Build type: native build
7.500       Project name: pandas
7.500       Project version: 2.1.4
7.500       
7.500       ../../meson.build:2:0: ERROR: Unknown compiler(s): [['cc'], ['gcc'], ['clang'], ['nvc'], ['pgcc'], ['icc'], ['icx']]
7.500       The following exception(s) were encountered:
7.500       Running `cc --version` gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'cc'"
7.500       Running `gcc --version` gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'gcc'"
7.500       Running `clang --version` gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'clang'"
7.500       Running `nvc --version` gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'nvc'"
7.500       Running `pgcc --version` gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'pgcc'"
7.500       Running `icc --version` gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'icc'"
7.500       Running `icx --version` gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'icx'"
7.500       
7.500       A full log can be found at /tmp/pip-install-k7rku_2t/pandas_873652e11bdc4d6295d70d48e70c056e/.mesonpy-304oy531/build/meson-logs/meson-log.txt
7.500       [end of output]
7.500   
7.500   note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
7.501 error: metadata-generation-failed
7.501 
7.501 × Encountered error while generating package metadata.
7.501 ╰─> See above for output.
7.501 
7.501 note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
7.501 hint: See above for details.
7.505 
7.505 [notice] A new release of pip is available: 23.2.1 -> 23.3.2
7.505 [notice] To update, run: pip install --upgrade pip
```

I've upgraded pip but that hasn't done anything. I'm missing gcc, cc, clang, etc. - is that the reason? Also, how do I download those if so?

Here are the contents of my docker file:

```html
# Set base image (host OS)
FROM python:3.12-alpine

# By default, listen on port 5000
EXPOSE 5000/tcp

# Set the working directory in the container
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the dependencies file to the working directory
COPY requirements.txt .

# Install any dependencies
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# Copy the content of the local src directory to the working directory
COPY app.py .

# Specify the command to run on container start
CMD [ "python", "./app.py" ]
```

Comment: You should edit your question to show your `Dockerfile`. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion - I've added the dockerfile contents.

Comment: You have to add a lot of dependencies in Alpine Linux before you can install Pandas. Se this question and answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54890328/installing-pandas-in-docker-alpine