# Docker: Alpine linux community package not found

Tags: docker, pip, docker-compose, repository, alpine-linux

I am trying to create a container with the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.6-alpine

RUN apk add --update alpine-sdk make gcc python3-dev python-dev libxslt-dev \
     libxml2-dev libc-dev openssl-dev libffi-dev zlib-dev py-pip openssh \
     py3-lxml@main py3-numpy@community \
     mariadb-dev libjpeg-dev zlib1g-dev && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*
```

I added `py3-lxml@main` and `py3-numpy@community` based on [this advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50443531/4764353) as building wheel for `numpy` and `lxml` takes ages.

I have used the package names as specified on the official [Alpine repo page](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages?name=*numpy&branch=v3.6), but I get the following error:

```
WARNING: The repository tag for world dependency 'py3-lxml@main' does not exist
WARNING: The repository tag for world dependency 'py3-numpy@community' does not exist*
```

Why is that and how can I get those packages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to fix this problem in specific:

```
WARNING: The repository tag for world dependency 'py3-lxml@main' does not exist
WARNING: The repository tag for world dependency 'py3-numpy@community' does not exist
```

You need to update the repositories file which is in here `/etc/apk/repositories`
to the following unless you want to remove the `@community` and `@main` tags from the `apk add` command as they are not written by default in the repositories file:

```
@main http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.9/main
@community http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.9/community
```

And don't forget to `COPY` it the content to `/etc/apk/repositories`

Comment: Thanks. I eneded up removing the  ```@community``` and ```@main``` tags. What do you mean by "And don't forget to COPY it the content to /etc/apk/repositories" - which content?

Comment: that was in case you decided to go with adding `@community` and `@main` as shown in my answer then you have to use `ADD repositories /etc/apk/repositories` to update the alpine image before usign `apk add`