# Installing Pandas for PyPy on Alpine Linux?

Tags: pandas, alpine-linux, pypy

As documented in the [following question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49037742/why-does-it-take-ages-to-install-pandas-on-alpine-linux)
, installing Pandas and Numpy is slow with Alpine Linux. For those using normal Python, there are workarounds that involve adding prebuilt versions of Pandas. However, these versions are for Python3. What is the best way to handle this with PyPy?

Answer (score 3):

the solution would be to provide prebuilt versions for Alpine Linux. Someone has to do the work of building them and uploading to a public site. It seems the distro provides these for cpython, perhaps they could be convinced to do so for pypy as well.

Answer (score 0):

New Versions of PyPy Already supports Pandas and Numpy

https://doc.pypy.org/en/latest/release-v5.9.0.html

So ,Official Image on docker should be supporting . So no need to build your Dockerfile from alpine

https://hub.docker.com/_/pypy

Comment: The problem is not installing Numpy/Pandas. The problem is installing Numpy/Pandas due to compiling.

Answer (score 0):

Do `update` first:

```
apk add --update py-pip
```

Or:

```
apk update
apk add py-pip
```

Or: install anaconda navigator : [Click Here](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/)

Or: Last option : [Click Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49057289/11283964)

Comment: The problem is not installing Numpy/Pandas. The problem is installing Numpy/Pandas due to compiling.