# PEP 656 (Musl Platform Tag) - Do i need to wait until support is added to the package in PyPi?

Tags: python, alpine-linux

I'm running Alpine Linux in a docker container. The app I'm deploying has most of the normal python data libraries installed (pandas, numpy, etc.).

Everything is 'working', but the install time for pandas is 15+ minutes. I'd like to speed it up if possible.

I read that PEP 656 (Musl Platform Tag) is supposed to help with this, but I'm not exactly sure of the actual next steps. Do i need to wait on the package maintainers to add a musl option to the package on PyPi, or is there something I can do now on my end to see these benefits?

I'm definitely not a Linux expert, so apologies if this is a basic question.

Comment: Are you using the Alpine Linux image as your base image and then adding the app and its dependencies? If so, as a workaround, you can instead setup an [Alpine Linux + pandas + other dependencies] as the base image, then just add your app during deployment.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does it take ages to install Pandas on Alpine Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49037742/why-does-it-take-ages-to-install-pandas-on-alpine-linux)