# Pandas error when installing on Gitlab runner YAML

Tags: pandas, numpy, gitlab, yaml

I am attempting to deploy a python AWS CDK app through a Gitlab runner automated deploy using a gitlab-ci.yml script. The failure is happening at the synth stage:

```
cdk-synth:
  stage: cdk-synth
  cache: []
  variables:
    CDK_PREFIX: $CDK_PREFIX
  tags:
    - aws-cdk
  image: node:14-alpine
  before_script:
    - apk add --no-cache python3 py3-pip
    - npm install -g aws-cdk@2.15.0
    - npm install -g cdk-assume-role-credential-plugin
    - python3 -m venv .venv
    - source .venv/bin/activate
    - pip install --upgrade pip
    - pip install -r requirements.txt
  script:
    - echo $CDK_PREFIX and "$CDK_PREFIX"
    - cdk synth
```

This script was working successfully without error until adding pandas to the requirements.txt file below:

```
aws-cdk-lib==2.15.0
constructs>=10.0.0,<11.0.0
urllib3==1.26.8
requests==2.27.1
boto3==1.20.51
pandas==1.4.0
```

The automated deploy pipeline is now failing with an error of:

```
Collecting pandas==1.4.0
  Downloading pandas-1.4.0.tar.gz (4.9 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 4.9/4.9 MB 93.8 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Installing build dependencies: started
  Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'error'
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error


ERROR: Could not build wheels for numpy, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I have attempted re-aligning the versions and updating pip without success. A google search suggests there is a dependency issue with the 'crypptography' package but does not suggest a clear fix besides uninstalling and re-installing pip which did not correct the issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Installing numpy on Docker Alpine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33421965/installing-numpy-on-docker-alpine)

Comment: No I am not using docker alpine

Comment: You are using image `image: node:14-alpine` which is pretty sure based on alpine

Comment: My mistake. I will see if there is an answer within the link posted.