# Building the docker image results in error while running "docker build -t file-name ."

Tags: docker, machine-learning, computer-vision, dockerfile, computer-science

I am working on a ml model which I am trying to containerise using Docker,
While running the command for
`docker build -t <file-name> <location>`

the below is the docker file.

```
FROM python:3.11-alpine
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app 
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt 
CMD streamlit run viz_app.python
```

And below is the error I'm getting.

```
22.34   note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
22.34 error: subprocess-exited-with-error
22.34 
22.34 × pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
22.34 │ exit code: 1
22.34 ╰─> See above for output.
22.34 
22.34 note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
22.36 
22.36 [notice] A new release of pip is available: 23.0.1 -> 23.3.1
22.36 [notice] To update, run: pip install --upgrade pip
------
Dockerfile:4
--------------------
   2 |     COPY . /app
   3 |     WORKDIR /app 
   4 | >>> RUN pip install -r requirements.txt 
   5 |     CMD streamlit run viz_app.python
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c pip install -r requirements.txt" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
```

I've tried to solve the particular issue using the approaches below.

- I tried upgrading the pip by mentioning "RUN pip install --upgrade pip"
- trying to install different version of packages of the requirement file also.

For further reference I'm adding the packages of requirement.txt file below.

```
numpy
pandas
streamlit
scikit-learn
matplotlib
opencv-python
tensorflow
segmentation-models
```

Comment: You seem to have cut off the interesting part of the error; can you [edit] the question to include the full error?  Python Alpine images can't use prebuilt Python "wheel" format packages, and it may resolve your issue to switch to a Debian-based image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to other topics it looks like numpy and alpine are not working the best together : [Alpine and numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33421965/installing-numpy-on-docker-alpine)

Is the alpine necessary ? Else you can use a basic python:3.11 image from docker and this should work correctly.

Moreover, you should give versions in your requirements.txt (for example pandas==2.0). This will alow you to have more control on the image / environment you are building in docker

Comment: thanks, it worked by just using a basic python:3.11 image