# Installing Pandas on Termux throws error: Broken toolchain

Tags: android, python, pandas

I've installed Termux (running on Android if that matters) and python (2.7 due to personal preference), but am running into the following issue when installing pandas:

```
RuntimeError: Broken toolchain: cannot link a simple C program
```

The same error is thrown for numpy and has something to do with the Cythonic nature of these modules.

Because I wanted to use python 2.7, I'm also using pip2 to install, not sure if that has any bearing on this.  And when I install `python-dev`, I actually use `python2-dev`.

A previous poster had [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22388519/problems-with-pip-install-numpy-runtimeerror-broken-toolchain-cannot-link-a) and it seems to have been fixed, but on Mac, the solution does not work for me.

Really, all I want to do is install python and pandas on Android, and I think Termux is the best solution, but I'm open to suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

Use these commands it will install all libraries like NumPy, pandas, matplotlib, jupyter, SciPy, scikit-learn:

```
apt install git
git clone https://github.com/sanheensethi/Installing-ML-In-Termux-Python.git
cd Installing-ML-In-Termux-Python
chmod +x ml-install.sh
ml-install.sh
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you `apt install python-dev`.  I believe when I ran into this issue it was because I was not using the -dev version, using the -dev version solved many issues for me.

I took some notes for myself at https://github.com/WaylonWalker/Python_Setup_Termux

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but I did do that and still am running into this issue.  Added some additional info to my original post.

Comment: I am currently running termux with python 3.6 and pandas on my LG G5.  Looking at my history.txt file i messed around trying to upgrade/install different compilers with no luck getting numpy installed.  My post was the solution that worked for me. I would try 3.6 and see if that works.

Comment: I have a feeling you're right about getting it to work with 3.6, but I can't make that leap just for this. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I was facing errors while installing numpy initally which was required for `pandas`. The way I installed numpy was

```
pkg install clang
pkg install python-dev
pip install numpy
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue more specifically is the error message around a simple c program. After installing clang, you'll be able to install pandas without the noted error.

```
pkg install clang
```