# Jupyter notebook on android using Termux doesn't upload files and recognize directories

Tags: android, python, jupyter-notebook, termux

I installed jupyter notebook on android via Termux, but I still can't open my .ipynb or .py, because I can't open directories neither upload a file.

This is my jupyter for opening files page:

[image: This is my jupyter for opening files page]

I get this when I'm trying to upload file:

[image: I get this when I'm trying to upload file]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22388519/problems-with-pip-install-numpy-runtimeerror-broken-toolchain-cannot-link-a

Answer (score 4):

Jupyter must be started from the directory containing the notebooks. Maybe this is the information you need.

I could not successfully install Jupyter on Termux on my Android devices (phone and tablet) due to errors when trying to install numpy.

So, I turned to an alternate solution which did work perfectly with no hassle:

I installed [Pydroid 3](https://www.google.ch/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://play.google.com/store/apps/details%3Fid%3Dru.iiec.pydroid3%26hl%3Den_US%26referrer%3Dutm_source%253Dgoogle%2526utm_medium%253Dorganic%2526utm_term%253Dpydroid%2B3%26pcampaignid%3DAPPU_1_QZvtWob6NsrUgAaBx6fgCQ&ved=0ahUKEwjGnqmywe7aAhVKKsAKHYHjCZwQ5IQBCCUwAA&usg=AOvVaw21bY7b8gtu4GhSK1IpUmn-), a Python 3.6 IDE for Android. Then, I pip installed within the IDE the required libraries (numpy, pandas, jupyter) without any difficulty.

To start Jupyter, I launched a terminal  using the relevant Pydroid menu.

And finally, I changed the directory to the one where I had dowloaded a whole bunch of Jupyter notebooks and launched Jupiter which automatically open the notebook tree in my browser:

[image: running Jupyter]

Fully executable notebook:

[image: Fully executable notebook]

Answer (score 1):

To install jupyter notebook into termux Android, you need to copy paste these codes one by one into termux terminal. (Note: for python programming language)

```
pkg remove game-repo
pkg remove science-repo
pkg update

apt install python
pkg install libzmq

pip install jupyter
```

After you have completed all these, just type *jupiter notebook* on termux terminal to open the jupyter every time. An url like "http://localhost:8870/?token=d2845af71c0d9b0ea3b43......abansk" (not complete real url, just an example) will come out and you will need to copy and paste into your browser.