# Installing pandas : RuntimeError: Broken toolchain: cannot link a simple C program

Tags: pandas, numpy, pip, python-3.4, windows-server-2012

I am trying to install pandas, but installation fails and giving me the below error. I am using Windows Server 2012 and Python 3.4. I have installed Visual Studio 2017 also.

When I tried the same with anaconda its working fine.

```
(env_one_site) D:\workspace\site> pip install pandas
    DEPRECATION: Python 3.4 support has been deprecated. pip 19.1 will be the last one supporting it. Please upgrade your Python as Python 3.4 won't be maintained after March 2019 (cf PEP 429).
    Collecting pandas
      Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/08/01/803834bc8a4e708aedebb133095a88a4dad9f45bbaf5ad777d2bea543c7e/pandas-0.22.0.tar.gz
      Installing build dependencies ... done
      Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
      Installing backend dependencies ... error
      Complete output from command d:\workspace\one_site_project\env_one_site\scripts\python.exe d:\workspace\one_site_project\env_one_site\lib\site-packages\pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix C:\Users\appadmin\AppData\Local
    \Temp\pip-build-env-mn1ok9zs\normal --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- numpy>=1.9.0:
      DEPRECATION: Python 3.4 support has been deprecated. pip 19.1 will be the last one supporting it. Please upgrade your Python as Python 3.4 won't be maintained after March 2019 (cf PEP 429).
      Collecting numpy>=1.9.0
        Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/93/48/956b9dcdddfcedb1705839280e02cbfeb2861ed5d7f59241210530867d5b/numpy-1.16.3.zip (5.1MB)
      Building wheels for collected packages: numpy
        Building wheel for numpy (setup.py): started
        Building wheel for numpy (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
        Complete output from command d:\workspace\one_site_project\env_one_site\scripts\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\appadmin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-rij08jgz\\numpy\\setup.py';f=getattr(tok
    enize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d C:\Users\appadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-_yjggw50 --python-tag cp34:
        Running from numpy source directory.
        blas_opt_info:
        blas_mkl_info:
        customize MSVCCompiler
          libraries mkl_rt not found in ['d:\\workspace\\one_site_project\\env_one_site\\lib', 'C:\\']
          NOT AVAILABLE
    
        blis_info:
        customize MSVCCompiler
          libraries blis not found in ['d:\\workspace\\one_site_project\\env_one_site\\lib', 'C:\\']
          NOT AVAILABLE
    
        openblas_info:
        customize MSVCCompiler
        customize MSVCCompiler
          libraries openblas not found in ['d:\\workspace\\one_site_project\\env_one_site\\lib', 'C:\\']
        get_default_fcompiler: matching types: '['gnu', 'intelv', 'absoft', 'compaqv', 'intelev', 'gnu95', 'g95', 'intelvem', 'intelem', 'flang']'
        customize GnuFCompiler
        Could not locate executable g77
        Could not locate executable f77
        customize IntelVisualFCompiler
        Could not locate executable ifort
        Could not locate executable ifl
        customize AbsoftFCompiler
        Could not locate executable f90
        customize CompaqVisualFCompiler
        Could not locate executable DF
      
    
        atlas_3_10_blas_info:
        customize MSVCCompiler
          libraries satlas not found in ['d:\\workspace\\one_site_project\\env_one_site\\lib', 'C:\\']
          NOT AVAILABLE
    
        atlas_blas_threads_info:
        Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
        customize MSVCCompiler
          libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in ['d:\\workspace\\one_site_project\\env_one_site\\lib', 'C:\\']
          NOT AVAILABLE
    
        atlas_blas_info:
        customize MSVCCompiler
          libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in ['d:\\workspace\\one_site_project\\env_one_site\\lib', 'C:\\']
          NOT AVAILABLE
    
        accelerate_info:
          NOT AVAILABLE
    
        C:\Users\appadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-rij08jgz\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:638: UserWarning:
            Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
            Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
            numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
            the ATLAS environment variable.
          self.calc_info()
        blas_info:
        customize MSVCCompiler
          libraries blas not found in ['d:\\workspace\\one_site_project\\env_one_site\\lib', 'C:\\']
          NOT AVAILABLE
    
        C:\Users\appadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-rij08jgz\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:638: UserWarning:
            Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
            Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
            numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
            the BLAS environment variable.
          self.calc_info()
        blas_src_info:
          NOT AVAILABLE
    
        C:\Users\appadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-rij08jgz\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:638: UserWarning:
            Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) sources not found.
            Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
            numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas_src]) or by setting
            the BLAS_SRC environment variable.
          self.calc_info()
          NOT AVAILABLE
    
        'svnversion' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
        operable program or batch file.
        non-existing path in 'numpy\\distutils': 'site.cfg'
        lapack_opt_info:
        lapack_mkl_info:
        customize MSVCCompiler
          libraries mkl_rt not found in ['d:\\workspace\\one_site_project\\env_one_site\\lib', 'C:\\']
          NOT AVAILABLE
    
        openblas_lapack_info:
        customize MSVCCompiler
        customize MSVCCompiler
          libraries openblas not found in ['d:\\workspace\\one_site_project\\env_one_site\\lib', 'C:\\']
          NOT AVAILABLE
    
        openblas_clapack_info:
        customize MSVCCompiler
        customize MSVCCompiler
          libraries openblas,lapack not found in ['d:\\workspace\\one_site_project\\env_one_site\\lib', 'C:\\']
          NOT AVAILABLE
       
        C:\Users\appadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-rij08jgz\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:638: UserWarning:
            Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
            Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
            numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
            the LAPACK environment variable.
          self.calc_info()
        lapack_src_info:
          NOT AVAILABLE
    
        C:\Users\appadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-rij08jgz\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:638: UserWarning:
            Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
            Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
            numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
            the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
          self.calc_info()
          NOT AVAILABLE
    
        C:\Python34\Lib\distutils\dist.py:260: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'define_macros'
          warnings.warn(msg)
        running bdist_wheel
        running build
        running config_cc
        unifing config_cc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --compiler options
        running config_fc
        unifing config_fc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --fcompiler options
        running build_src
        build_src
        building py_modules sources
        creating build
        creating build\src.win-amd64-3.4
        creating build\src.win-amd64-3.4\numpy
        creating build\src.win-amd64-3.4\numpy\distutils
        building library "npymath" sources
        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\Bin\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -Inumpy\core\src\common -Inumpy\core\src -Inumpy\core -Inumpy\core\src\npymath -Inumpy\core\src\multiarray -Inumpy\core\src\umat
    h -Inumpy\core\src\npysort -IC:\Python34\include -IC:\Python34\include /Tc_configtest.c /Fo_configtest.obj
        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\Bin\link.exe /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /MANIFEST _configtest.obj /OUT:_configtest.exe /MANIFESTFILE:_configtest.exe.manifest
        LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'MSVCRT.lib'
        failure.
        removing: _configtest.c _configtest.obj _configtest.obj.d
        Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
          File "C:\Users\appadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-rij08jgz\numpy\setup.py", line 415, in <module>
            setup_package()
          File "C:\Users\appadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-rij08jgz\numpy\setup.py", line 407, in setup_package
            setup(**metadata)
          File "C:\Users\appadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-rij08jgz\numpy\numpy\distutils\core.py", line 171, in setup
         
            cmd_obj.run()
          File "C:\Users\appadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-rij08jgz\numpy\numpy\distutils\command\build_src.py", line 148, in run
            self.build_sources()
          File "C:\Users\appadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-rij08jgz\numpy\numpy\distutils\command\build_src.py", line 159, in build_sources
            self.build_library_sources(*libname_info)
          File "C:\Users\appadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-rij08jgz\numpy\numpy\distutils\command\build_src.py", line 292, in build_library_sources
            sources = self.generate_sources(sources, (lib_name, build_info))
          File "C:\Users\appadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-rij08jgz\numpy\numpy\distutils\command\build_src.py", line 375, in generate_sources
            source = func(extension, build_dir)
          File "numpy\core\setup.py", line 667, in get_mathlib_info
            raise RuntimeError("Broken toolchain: cannot link a simple C program")
        RuntimeError: Broken toolchain: cannot link a simple C program
    
        ----------------------------------------
        Failed building wheel for numpy
        Running setup.py clean for numpy
        Complete output from command d:\workspace\one_site_project\env_one_site\scripts\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\appadmin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-rij08jgz\\numpy\\setup.py';f=getattr(tok
    enize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" clean --all:
        Running from numpy source directory.
    
        `setup.py clean` is not supported, use one of the following instead:
    
          - `git clean -xdf` (cleans all files)
          - `git clean -Xdf` (cleans all versioned files, doesn't touch
                              files that aren't checked into the git repo)
    
        Add `--force` to your command to use it anyway if you must (unsupported).
    
    
        ----------------------------------------
        Failed cleaning build dir for numpy
      Failed to build numpy
      Installing collected packages: numpy
        Running setup.py install for numpy: started
          Running setup.py install for numpy: finished with status 'error'
          Complete output from command d:\workspace\one_site_project\env_one_site\scripts\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\appadmin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-rij08jgz\\numpy\\setup.py';f=getattr(t
    okenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\appadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-hx4uurea\install-record.txt --single-version-externa
    lly-managed --prefix C:\Users\appadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-mn1ok9zs\normal --compile --install-headers d:\workspace\one_site_project\env_one_site\include\site\python3.4\numpy:
          Running from numpy source directory.
    
          Note: if you need reliable uninstall behavior, then install
          with pip instead of using `setup.py install`:
    
            - `pip install .`       (from a git repo or downloaded source
                                     release)
            - `pip install numpy`   (last NumPy release on PyPi)
    
    
          blas_opt_info:
          blas_mkl_info:
          customize MSVCCompiler
            libraries mkl_rt not found in ['d:\\workspace\\one_site_project\\env_one_site\\lib', 'C:\\']
            NOT AVAILABLE
    
          blis_info:
          customize MSVCCompiler
            libraries blis not found in ['d:\\workspace\\one_site_project\\env_one_site\\lib', 'C:\\']
            NOT AVAILABLE
    
          openblas_info:
          customize MSVCCompiler
          customize MSVCCompiler
            libraries openblas not found in ['d:\\workspace\\one_site_project\\env_one_site\\lib', 'C:\\']
          get_default_fcompiler: matching types: '['gnu', 'intelv', 'absoft', 'compaqv', 'intelev', 'gnu95', 'g95', 'intelvem', 'intelem', 'flang']'
          customize GnuFCompiler
          Could not locate executable g77
          Could not locate executable f77
          customize IntelVisualFCompiler
          Could not locate executable ifort
          Could not locate executable ifl
          customize AbsoftFCompiler
          Could not locate executable f90
          customize CompaqVisualFCompiler
          Could not locate executable DF
          customize IntelItaniumVisualFCompiler
          Could not locate executable efl
          customize Gnu95FCompiler
          Could not locate executable gfortran
          Could not locate executable f95
          customize G95FCompiler
          Could not locate executable g95
          customize IntelEM64VisualFCompiler
          customize IntelEM64TFCompiler
          Could not locate executable efort
          Could not locate executable efc
          customize PGroupFlangCompiler
          don't know how to compile Fortran code on platform 'nt'
            NOT AVAILABLE
    
          atlas_3_10_blas_threads_info:
          Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
          customize MSVCCompiler
            libraries tatlas not found in ['d:\\workspace\\one_site_project\\env_one_site\\lib', 'C:\\']
            NOT AVAILABLE
    
          atlas_3_10_blas_info:
          customize MSVCCompiler
            libraries satlas not found in ['d:\\workspace\\one_site_project\\env_one_site\\lib', 'C:\\']
            NOT AVAILABLE
    
          atlas_blas_threads_info:
          Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
          customize MSVCCompiler
            libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in ['d:\\workspace\\one_site_project\\env_one_site\\lib', 'C:\\']
            NOT AVAILABLE
    
          atlas_blas_info:
          customize MSVCCompiler
            libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in ['d:\\workspace\\one_site_project\\env_one_site\\lib', 'C:\\']
            NOT AVAILABLE
    
          accelerate_info:
            NOT AVAILABLE
    
          C:\Users\appadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-rij08jgz\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:638: UserWarning:
              Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
              Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
              numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
              the ATLAS environment variable.
            self.calc_info()
          blas_info:
          customize MSVCCompiler
            libraries blas not found in ['d:\\workspace\\one_site_project\\env_one_site\\lib', 'C:\\']
            NOT AVAILABLE
    
          C:\Users\appadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-rij08jgz\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:638: UserWarning:
              Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
              Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
              numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
              the BLAS environment variable.
            self.calc_info()
          blas_src_info:
            NOT AVAILABLE
    
          C:\Users\appadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-rij08jgz\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:638: UserWarning:
              Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) sources not found.
              Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
              numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas_src]) or by setting
              the BLAS_SRC environment variable.
            self.calc_info()
            NOT AVAILABLE
    
          'svnversion' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
          operable program or batch file.
          non-existing path in 'numpy\\distutils': 'site.cfg'
          lapack_opt_info:
          lapack_mkl_info:
          customize MSVCCompiler
            libraries mkl_rt not found in ['d:\\workspace\\one_site_project\\env_one_site\\lib', 'C:\\']
            NOT AVAILABLE
    
          openblas_lapack_info:
          customize MSVCCompiler
          customize MSVCCompiler
            libraries openblas not found in ['d:\\workspace\\one_site_project\\env_one_site\\lib', 'C:\\']
            NOT AVAILABLE
    
          openblas_clapack_info:
          customize MSVCCompiler
          customize MSVCCompiler
            libraries openblas,lapack not found in ['d:\\workspace\\one_site_project\\env_one_site\\lib', 'C:\\']
            NOT AVAILABLE
    
          atlas_3_10_threads_info:
          Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
          customize MSVCCompiler
            libraries lapack_atlas not found in d:\workspace\one_site_project\env_one_site\lib
          customize MSVCCompiler
            libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in d:\workspace\one_site_project\env_one_site\lib
          customize MSVCCompiler
            libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
          customize MSVCCompiler
            libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\
          <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
            NOT AVAILABLE
    
          atlas_3_10_info:
          customize MSVCCompiler
            libraries lapack_atlas not found in d:\workspace\one_site_project\env_one_site\lib
          customize MSVCCompiler
            libraries satlas,satlas not found in d:\workspace\one_site_project\env_one_site\lib
          customize MSVCCompiler
            libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
          customize MSVCCompiler
            libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\
          <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
            NOT AVAILABLE
    
          atlas_threads_info:
          Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
          customize MSVCCompiler
            libraries lapack_atlas not found in d:\workspace\one_site_project\env_one_site\lib
          customize MSVCCompiler
            libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in d:\workspace\one_site_project\env_one_site\lib
          customize MSVCCompiler
            libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
          customize MSVCCompiler
            libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\
          <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
            NOT AVAILABLE
    
          atlas_info:
          customize MSVCCompiler
            libraries lapack_atlas not found in d:\workspace\one_site_project\env_one_site\lib
          customize MSVCCompiler
            libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in d:\workspace\one_site_project\env_one_site\lib
          customize MSVCCompiler
            libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
          customize MSVCCompiler
            libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\
          <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
            NOT AVAILABLE
    
          lapack_info:
          customize MSVCCompiler
            libraries lapack not found in ['d:\\workspace\\one_site_project\\env_one_site\\lib', 'C:\\']
            NOT AVAILABLE
    
          build_src
          building py_modules sources
          building library "npymath" sources
          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\Bin\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -Inumpy\core\src\common -Inumpy\core\src -Inumpy\core -Inumpy\core\src\npymath -Inumpy\core\src\multiarray -Inumpy\core\src\um
    ath -Inumpy\core\src\npysort -IC:\Python34\include -IC:\Python34\include /Tc_configtest.c /Fo_configtest.obj
          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\Bin\link.exe /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /MANIFEST _configtest.obj /OUT:_configtest.exe /MANIFESTFILE:_configtest.exe.manifest
          LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'MSVCRT.lib'
          failure.
          removing: _configtest.c _configtest.obj _configtest.obj.d
          Traceback (most recent call last):
            File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
            File "C:\Users\appadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-rij08jgz\numpy\setup.py", line 415, in <module>
              setup_package()
            File "C:\Users\appadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-rij08jgz\numpy\setup.py", line 407, in setup_package
              setup(**metadata)
            File "C:\Users\appadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-rij08jgz\numpy\numpy\distutils\core.py", line 171, in setup
              return old_setup(**new_attr)
            File "d:\workspace\one_site_project\env_one_site\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 145, in setup
              return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
            File "C:\Python34\Lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
              dist.run_commands()
            File "C:\Python34\Lib\distutils\dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
              self.run_command(cmd)
            File "C:\Python34\Lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
              cmd_obj.run()
            File "C:\Users\appadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-rij08jgz\numpy\numpy\distutils\command\install.py", line 62, in run
              r = self.setuptools_run()
            File "C:\Users\appadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-rij08jgz\numpy\numpy\distutils\command\install.py", line 36, in setuptools_run
              return distutils_install.run(self)
            File "C:\Python34\Lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 539, in run
              self.run_command('build')
            File "C:\Python34\Lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
              self.distribution.run_command(command)
            File "C:\Python34\Lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
              cmd_obj.run()
            File "C:\Users\appadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-rij08jgz\numpy\numpy\distutils\command\build.py", line 47, in run
              old_build.run(self)
            File "C:\Python34\Lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 126, in run
              self.run_command(cmd_name)
            File "C:\Python34\Lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
              self.distribution.run_command(command)
            File "C:\Python34\Lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
              cmd_obj.run()
            File "C:\Users\appadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-rij08jgz\numpy\numpy\distutils\command\build_src.py", line 148, in run
              self.build_sources()
            File "C:\Users\appadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-rij08jgz\numpy\numpy\distutils\command\build_src.py", line 159, in build_sources
              self.build_library_sources(*libname_info)
            File "C:\Users\appadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-rij08jgz\numpy\numpy\distutils\command\build_src.py", line 292, in build_library_sources
              sources = self.generate_sources(sources, (lib_name, build_info))
            File "C:\Users\appadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-rij08jgz\numpy\numpy\distutils\command\build_src.py", line 375, in generate_sources
              source = func(extension, build_dir)
            File "numpy\core\setup.py", line 667, in get_mathlib_info
              raise RuntimeError("Broken toolchain: cannot link a simple C program")
          RuntimeError: Broken toolchain: cannot link a simple C program
    
          ----------------------------------------
      Command "d:\workspace\one_site_project\env_one_site\scripts\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\appadmin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-rij08jgz\\numpy\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(_
    _file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\appadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-hx4uurea\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --prefix C:\
    Users\appadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-mn1ok9zs\normal --compile --install-headers d:\workspace\one_site_project\env_one_site\include\site\python3.4\numpy" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\appadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-i
    nstall-rij08jgz\numpy\
      You are using pip version 19.0.3, however version 19.1 is available.
      You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
    
      ----------------------------------------
    Command "d:\workspace\one_site_project\env_one_site\scripts\python.exe d:\workspace\one_site_project\env_one_site\lib\site-packages\pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix C:\Users\appadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-mn
    1ok9zs\normal --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- numpy>=1.9.0" failed with error code 1 in None
```

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22388519/problems-with-pip-install-numpy-runtimeerror-broken-toolchain-cannot-link-a) question, but it is for OSX. I am using a Windows Server 2012 machine.

Comment: `pip install pandas --only-binary=pandas,numpy,scipy`; if more packages will fail the build, add them to the list. Beware that Python 3.4 is outdated and not supported, so you won't be able to install the latest versions of precompiled `pandas`, `numpy` etc anymore. You can try build them from source, but first you need to install `openblas` for windows, setup the MSVC compiler etc.

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar error.  My solution was to use python3.7 for venv instead of python3.8

Answer (score -1):

upgrade the pip using this command: `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`

then install the library: `pip install yourlibrary`