# Problems in installing Numpy in Pycharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, installation, pycharm

I don't know for what reasons I am getting this error while installing Numpy in Pycharm. Although I have already installed Numpy in my system which is Windows based with the help of command prompt. But still I am still getting this error and also I have latest version of Pycharm.

RuntimeError: Broken toolchain: cannot link a simple C program

Can somebody help me?

Comment: Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22388519/problems-with-pip-install-numpy-runtimeerror-broken-toolchain-cannot-link-a The answer should help you out.

Comment: As I mentioned in my post I am getting this error while installing in pycharm. I have already installed Numpy without any issues in my sytem. But I am not able to install in Pycharm

Comment: Pycharm can point to an anaconda environment, which is likely the best way to go for testing/implementing.

Answer (score 0):

To properly install Numpy in Pycharm, you have to go to **File/Settings/Project Interpreter** click on add and search for numpy in the search bar.

Click on install package, it should run and install with no problem

Comment: Yup tried in the same manner but still it's throwing the same error.