# Message "error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required."

Tags: pip, python-packaging, allennlp

While downloading `pip install allennlp==1.0.0 allennlp-models==1.0.0`, I faced this problem:

```
        [6 lines of output]
        running bdist_wheel
        running build
        running build_py
        running build_ext
        building 'srsly.msgpack._unpacker' extension
        error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
        [end of output]

        note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
        ERROR: Failed building wheel for srsly
      Failed to build thinc blis srsly
      ERROR: Could not build wheels for srsly, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

I have downloaded:

```
pip install -vvv torch
pip install numpy
pip3 install --pre torch -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/nightly/cpu/torch_nightly.html
```

and it still not working.

I am using Python 3.10.2 on [Windows 11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_11) Pro.

What should I do?

Comment: "error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/"—did you try this? The error tells you what the problem is and how to fix it.

Comment: @Chris This method did not work, same problem, thanks for your comment

Comment: What does "did not work" mean? Are you still getting the same error message? Then it was not done correctly, or at least the Python build tools can't find it. And if you're getting a _different_ error message, please share it with us.

Comment: This is a pretty old version of AllenNLP. Do you really need to install a version this old?

Comment: It would be nice if `pip` could capture the original error, display the "subprocess, not me" boilerplate first, *then* end with the "real" error that you need to address.

Answer (score 44):

I had Python 3.10 and had the same error installing psutil from pip. I fixed the problem by installing an older version of pip using the command:

```
pip install pip==21.3.1
```

Comment: Didn't work for me `ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:`, `ERROR: Failed building wheel for rpi.gpio` after trying to install rpi.gpio after using this method since I had the same error as the question originally

Comment: I had Python 3.8.10. Installing pip upgrade to latest version caused this issue. Downgrading it back down to v20.0.2 did it for me.

Comment: downgrading pip works for me

Answer (score 11):

I have tried multiple solution it didn't worked. Finally found working solution. run the below command.

```
pip install wheel setuptools pip --upgrade
```

Comment: This worked for me!

Chip Apple M1 Pro

pip version 23.2.1

Answer (score 6):

You have to install the Python 3.9.10 version from python.org and after installation, upgrade your pip and everything will be sorted.

It is the problem in Python 3.10.2... This method is working. I was suffering from the same problem in installing the turtle, so I did that and error was solved.

Comment: It didn't work for me, same problem.

Answer (score 4):

To solve this problem, you need to download Visual Studio from [its main page](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/).

If Visual Studio is already installed, then when you run the installer, you can modify it (by clicking the modify button):

[image]

During Visual Studio installation (or installation modification) choose *Desktop Development with C++*:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you're using a Python 3 image, this might help:

```
RUN apk update
RUN apk add make automake gcc g++ subversion python3-dev
```

Reference from *[Problems with pip install numpy - RuntimeError: Broken toolchain: cannot link a simple C program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22388519/problems-with-pip-install-numpy-runtimeerror-broken-toolchain-cannot-link-a)*

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required.

You must be install build visual tools 15, 17, 19, or greater.

Download from *[Microsoft C++ Build Tools](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/)*.

Answer (score 2):

https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/

Download and install or update

Comment: I do not see how this answers the question at the top of this page, but it should. Please [edit] according to [answer] or delete the answer. Otherwise it risks being flagged as "not an answer" and being deleted.

Answer (score 1):

This particular error is caused by not having a C/C++ compiler installed. As said in the error message, either install [MSVC](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/) or another compiler to compile it.

Please read your error messages; they are there for a reason.

Comment: I downloaded and installed it but I got the same problem again, I don't know why, but I tried all the ways I got and it didn't work

Comment: @AhmadSadekAlbasatneh Have you tried restarting you computer?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem while installing with pip3: **building wheel for box2d-py (setup.py) ... error**

**The solution** was just to install [SWIG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SWIG) prior to box2d, so I added the following steps manually:

1. pip install swig
2. pip install gym[box2d]

Comment: It worked for me using Google colab

Answer (score 1):

First: You installed the [Mingw-w64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mingw-w64) compiler with a full MSYS2 package, and this package included Python.

Second: you get the error because the plugin is not in the Python packages installed by MSYS2.

So: uninstall MSYS2 and install a minimalistic [MinGW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MinGW) ([MinGW - minimalistic GNU for Windows](https://osdn.net/projects/mingw/downloads/68260/mingw-get-setup.exe/)).

And finally Install a version of Python from the official Python page.
Now if you can install plugins.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a similar question from [GitHub](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/981#issuecomment-1015463131), and credits goes to [thaibee](https://github.com/thaibee). Here I quote:

> It's a problem with Microsoft products and is
> very easy to solve.
>
> If you can't install these plugins as well,
> need to download it from other repositories like this one:
>
> [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/) depends on the version of python and the system.
>
> For example: for my Windows 11 (x64) and Python 3.10 I took this file:   pyodbc‑4.0.32‑cp310‑cp310‑win_amd64.whl
>
> It's very easy to install: pip install pyodbc‑4.0.32‑cp310‑cp310‑win_amd64.whl
>
> After it, the system works well and didn't ask you about VC.
>
> This solution I found in problem with the MySQL plugin for Django. I don't understand why - but they also use VC for the installation process.

Comment: _Of course_ it's possible to build from source with the right build tools. Where do you think Christoph Gohlke's packages come from? It may be trickier than it is on other platforms, but it's definitely possible.

Comment: Some models are not found in: https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Answer (score 0):

I understand your problem, and I have faced it too. I tried multiple solutions, but it didn't work, so I simply uninstalled my Python and installed some older version of it. Example: I recently uninstalled Python 3.10.2 and installed 3.9.10.

It worked without any errors.

Comment: It didn't work for me, same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem when executing:

```
python -m pip install package-name
```

After many failed tentatives, what fixed the problem for me was executing:

```
py -m pip install package-name
```

When I type py in the terminal, it shows this information:

```
Python 3.9.8 (tags/v3.9.8:bb3fdcf, Nov  5 2021, 20:48:33) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
```

When I type `python` in the terminal, it shows this information:

```
Python 3.8.2 (default, Apr  9 2020, 13:17:39)  [GCC 9.3.0 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
```

I believe that this problem is related to the Python interpreter version.

Comment: You're using two different compilers. It is more likely that using MSVC is what solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For Mac, there is a possible workaround for this problem if you use [Conda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conda_(package_manager)). The idea is to create an [x86](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IA-32) environment on the Mac and do your pip install after that.

```
conda create -n <name>
conda activate <name>
conda config --env --set subdir osx-64
conda install python=3.8
```

Here I choose Python 3.8, but you can choose another version.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on [macOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS) (maybe [Apple silicon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_silicon)) then first try to do this from your base location of the terminal:

```
eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"
```

Then, do `brew update` and `brew upgrade`.

Once you are done with that, type

```
brew install geos
```

Now again go to your virtual environment and activate it (if you are working in the [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv)) and then type:

```
python3.10 -m pip3 install [module name]
```

Answer (score 0):

I see this error because i use the msys2's Python to creat a venv python.This because My Windows is new And I not install Python,but I setup msys2 to install MinGW.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue installing with pip or conda in a conda environment. I solved it only with PyCharm by ask it to install the package, in my case, gdal.

So, I chose my env and it offer to install by itself since the *gdal==3.6.2* was in my **requirements.txt** file.

Answer (score 0):

Many of the machine learning libraries doesnot support python 32 bit,so solution is to shift to 64 bit python

Answer (score -1):

I tried all recommendations that were written, but none worked. My Python was 3.11.

So I just installed Python 3.8.10 from here:

```
https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-3810/
```

And ran

```
C:\Python38\python.exe -m pip install matplotlib
```

And it worked.

Answer (score -2):

We can install DVC with the below commands:

```
conda install -c conda-forge mamba # installs much faster than conda

mamba install -c conda-forge dvc
```

For more information please refer this: https://dvc.org/doc/install/

Comment: What has this to do with the question? An explanation would be in in order. Is it a response to [Marcelo Archanjo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71009659/message-note-this-error-originates-from-a-subprocess-and-is-likely-not-a-prob/73828390#73828390)?

Answer (score -2):

I faced a similar problem while installing pandas-datareader.

I was using Python 3.11.0, and after trying all possible solutions, I downloaded Python 9.10.0 and it worked fine.

Comment: *'python v9.10.0'* -- Did you mean v3.9.10?