# When I was installing the imageAI library, I faced this issue

Tags: python, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence

I am facing some issues regarding installing the imageAI library, I have tried too many times to install this.

[image]

Comment: what python package are you trying to install

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please post your full error as text and not as an image.

Comment: @Whereismywall imageAI library..

Comment: please give output of pip list

Comment: A incomplete screenshot is not an acceptable form to present an error here, we cannot even see the complete error which is outside of the screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem once related to having different versions of python accessing different compilers on my pc.

borrowing from the discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71009659/note-this-error-originates-from-a-subprocess-and-is-likely-not-a-problem-with) you can either uninstall python from your pc and then install the python 3.9.10 version from python.org and after installtion upgrade your pip (apparently some people had this problem using version 3.10) or verify if you have two versions conflicting to access pip by running:

```
python -m pip install package-name
```

and also

```
py -m pip install package-name
```

if there is a problem with version or conflict, one of these two lines will return which one is working and which one is having a problem

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error..

**Solution:**

install Imageai using whl

download imageai whl from [here](https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/73/44/3d5d8ef572888025666eec284e85f9243faf06ca8c12085dcff1ca9754ed/imageai-2.1.6-py3-none-any.whl)

and install using below command

```
pip install <whl file location>
```