# Error Installing Symspellpy in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, symspellpy

I am trying to install symspell in jupyter notebook but I'm getting this error:

```
    error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  Building wheel for editdistpy (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  exit code: 1
  
  [15 lines of output]
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_ext
  building 'editdistpy.levenshtein' extension
  creating build
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-39
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-39\Release
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-39\Release\editdistpy
  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\x86_amd64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Ieditdistpy -I./editdistpy -IC:\Users\nuwai\anaconda3\include -IC:\Users\yaa\anaconda3\Include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt" /EHsc /Tpeditdistpy/_levenshtein.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-39\Release\editdistpy/_levenshtein.obj
  _levenshtein.cpp
  editdistpy/_levenshtein.cpp(104): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'int64_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\x86_amd64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Ieditdistpy -I./editdistpy -IC:\Users\nuwai\anaconda3\include -IC:\Users\yaa\anaconda3\Include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt" /EHsc /Tpeditdistpy/levenshtein.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-39\Release\editdistpy/levenshtein.obj
  levenshtein.cpp
  c:\users\yaa\anaconda3\include\pyconfig.h(200): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'basetsd.h': No such file or directory
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\x86_amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
  [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for editdistpy
ERROR: Could not build wheels for editdistpy, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

It says the error is originated from a subprocess in which I'm not sure where. I have updated my pip version and tried other solutions but it is still not working. Mind helping out? I'm not sure what to do to solve this error to install symspell python.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Running Cython in Windows x64 - fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'basetsd.h': No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23691564/running-cython-in-windows-x64-fatal-error-c1083-cannot-open-include-file-ba)

Comment: My problem is resolved! The reference:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/73362144/21435296