# Can't install opencv, errors with getting requirements to build wheel

Tags: python, opencv, installation, pip

```
Collecting opencv-python
  Using cached opencv-python-4.8.0.76.tar.gz (92.1 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [79 lines of output]
      Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.6" and platform_machine != "aarch64" and platform_machine != "arm64"' don't match your environment
      Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.7" and platform_machine != "aarch64" and platform_machine != "arm64"' don't match your environment
      Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.8" and platform_machine != "aarch64" and platform_machine != "arm64"' don't match your environment
      Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version <= "3.9" and sys_platform == "linux" and platform_machine == "aarch64"' don't match your environment
      Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version <= "3.9" and sys_platform == "darwin" and platform_machine == "arm64"' don't match your environment
      Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.9" and platform_machine != "aarch64" and platform_machine != "arm64"' don't match your environment
      Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.10" and platform_system == "Darwin"' don't match your environment
      Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version >= "3.11"' don't match your environment
      Collecting numpy==1.21.2
        Using cached numpy-1.21.2.zip (10.3 MB)
        Installing build dependencies: started
        Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
        Getting requirements to build wheel: started
        Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'error'
        error: subprocess-exited-with-error

        Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
        exit code: 1

        note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
      error: subprocess-exited-with-error

      Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
      exit code: 1

      See above for output.

      note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

I have tried installing cmake, similar error shown, tried updating pip, setuptools and wheel, didn't help either.

If it helps, I'm trying to install the packages into a virtual environment (venv).

Any solution to this? Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: did you try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71009659/message-note-this-error-originates-from-a-subprocess-and-is-likely-not-a-prob)

Comment: ill give it a try, thanks :)

Comment: yup seems to be working now, must've had a version mismatch between pip and my current python version, thanks again