# Error: griddb_python installation error on jupyter notebook

Tags: python, installation, griddb

I'm trying to install griddb_python library on jupyter notebook. I'm getting this error
**Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting griddb_python
Using cached griddb_python-0.7.6.tar.gz (52 kB)
Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: griddb_python
Building wheel for griddb_python (setup.py) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [399 lines of output]
running bdist_wheel
The [wheel] section is deprecated. Use [bdist_wheel] instead.
running build
running build_ext
building '_griddb_python' extension
swigging src/griddb.i to src/griddb_wrap.cpp
swig -python -DSWIGWORDSIZE64 -c++ -outdir . -Isrc -o src/griddb_wrap.cpp src/griddb.i
creating build
.
.
.

```
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

ERROR: Failed building wheel for griddb_python
Running setup.py clean for griddb_python
Failed to build griddb_python
Installing collected packages: griddb_python
Running setup.py install for griddb_python ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Running setup.py install for griddb_python did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1

```
  **
```

I have tried solutions from these resources
[Message "note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71009659/message-note-this-error-originates-from-a-subprocess-and-is-likely-not-a-prob)
https://github.com/NVIDIA/apex/issues/1598

I have tried this with python Python 2.7.18 and Python 3.9 but having the same issue. I'm using ubuntu. Can someone help me out here?

Comment: You don't give any specific on what you are trying? And so just providing the error of one command doesn't help anyone help you much. Did you try running inside the notebook where you want to use it, `%pip install numpy` and `%pip install pandas` before trying in the notebook `%pip install griddb-python` then restarting the kernel and then try the import?

Comment: Yes can install other libraries like numpy and matplotlib inside jupyter notebook. But getting this error when I try to install griddb-python.

Comment: Does it matter where you get this working in particular? I was able to install it on a remote system that I can tell you how to use.