# Installing psycopg2

Tags: python, macos, psycopg2

I get the following error when I try to install psycopg2

> building 'psycopg2._psycopg' extension
>
> clang -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -g -Os -pipe
>   -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -mno-fused-madd -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wshorten-64-to-32 -DNDEBUG -g -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -pipe -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.4.5 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x090104 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1
>   -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7
>   -I. -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/psycopgmodule.c -o
>   build/temp.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7/psycopg/psycopgmodule.o
>
> unable to execute clang: No such file or directory
>
> error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the error message, you are missing the clang package in order to compile psycopg2.

From the tags on the question, I take you're on osx, perhaps the following link will help you getting and installing it:
http://woss.name/2012/01/24/how-to-install-a-working-set-of-compilers-on-mac-os-x-10-7-lion/

Answer (score 1):

To get clang, first install Xcode then install the command line tools from within Xcode.

Here's a stackoverflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329243/xcode-4-4-command-line-tools) about it.