# QT Project unable to compile, no compiler available to build

Tags: c++, macos, qt

I'm running Mountain Lion and I've installed QT Library 4.8

[From this page...](http://qt-project.org/downloads)
Qt libraries 4.8.4 for Mac (185 MB)

I've also installed Qt Creator 2.6.1 for Mac (Intel 32/64bit) (51 MB) from the same page.

When I attempt to run, I get this error:

> 18:14:01: Could not start process "make" -w Error while
>   building/deploying project WebBrowser (target: Desktop) When executing
>   step 'Make'

I will include my build setup in three screenshots

[image: Kits]
[image: QT Versions]
[image: Compilers]

Any ideas?

Comment: could be your qt didn't install correctly as the compiler could not be found, if worse comes to worse try uninstalling QT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you didn't install the UNIX command line tools package of XCode. Install that and it should work. See here on how to install the UNIX tools in XCode:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9329325/856199

There are also stand-alone versions of the UNIX command line development tools if you don't want to install XCode. You can find them here:

https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action

Look for "Command Line Tools (OS X Mountain Lion) for XCode". Get the latest version.

Comment: I've installed Xcode from the app store and it's making no difference. It still won't auto detect any of the above! Hmmmmm! Maybe I'll manually try and find the xcode compiler?

Comment: Nowadays one has to trigger the installation via the XCode preferences, after installation: Preferences -> Downloads -> Command Line Tools

Comment: @Luke Well, you can also uninstall XCode and install only the UNIX tools. Link in answer.

Comment: I've got that working and now it's changed slightly. It's now throwing up more errors. I'll add a screenshot to the question!

Comment: @Luke This is a different issue, so please create a new question for that. Your original question has been answered :-)

Comment: @NikosC. that's fair enough, i used another question for that. I've removed the additional error and will green tick this question now. Thanks for the help.