# Can't install Ruby on Mountain Lion with rvm

Tags: ruby, rvm, osx-mountain-lion, homebrew

Have tried to install Ruby on Mountain Lion using rvm, but got this error message:

```
ruby-1.9.3-p362 - #extracted to /usr/local/rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p362
ruby-1.9.3-p362 - #configuring
Error running 'env LDFLAGS=-L/opt/sm/pkg/active/lib CFLAGS=-I/opt/sm/pkg/active/include CPATH=/opt/sm/pkg/active/include ./configure --enable-shared --disable-install-doc --prefix=/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p362 --with-opt-dir=/usr/local/rvm/usr', please read /usr/local/rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p362/configure.log
There has been an error while running configure. Halting the installation.
ruby-1.9.3-p362 is not installed.
Creating alias default for ruby-1.9.3-p362.
Recording alias default for ruby-1.9.3-p362.
Creating default links/files
ruby-1.9.3-p362 is not installed.
Could not load ruby ruby-1.9.3-p362.
/usr/local/rvm/scripts/alias: line 111: /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p362/bin/ruby: No such file or directory
```

What can I do to get a proper install of Ruby working? Also have Homebrew package manager installed; is there a conflict?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you include the contents of `/usr/local/rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p362/configure.log`, or at least the last few lines?

Answer (score 12):

It's probably due to the fact that recent versions of OS X use the LLVM instead of defaulting to the GCC compiler.

Try this:

```
brew update
brew tap homebrew/dupes
brew install apple-gcc42
```

to install the GCC compiler. Then:

```
rvm install 1.9.3 --with-gcc=clang`
```

**EDIT:**
If the previous solution doesn't work, try giving the following a try before running `rvm install 1.9.3`:

`export CC=/usr/local/bin/gcc-4.2`

**EDIT 2:**
The following github page outlines the issue and multiple solutions, added to this post for documentation purposes: [Installation tips for RVM/Ruby on OSX 10.8 Mountain Lion](https://gist.github.com/3237860)

Comment: Tried the 'brew install apple-gcc42' command but got a 'No available formula' response. Any other suggestions?

Comment: You'll need to run the two previous brew commands in order to have the apple-gcc42 formula be available. The first one (`brew update`) does just what it says and the second (`brew tap homebrew/dupes`) allows you to access the formulas available at [this github page](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-dupes), which includes `apple-gcc42` - the compiler you need. Let me know if it fails and I'll look for another solution. I verified on my own machine that the commands should work as I originally presented them.

Comment: Yes, I did run the two previous commands. For the 'brew update' command, got 'Already up-to-date' and for the 'brew tap homebrew/dupes' command, got 'Already tapped!'. But when I get to the 'brew install apple-gcc42' command, still get 'Error: No available formula for apple-gcc42'. Thank you.

Comment: Ok, a couple more potential solutions - Run the following commands: `brew install autoconf automake`; `brew install https://raw.github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-dupes/master/apple-gcc42.rb`; `rvm get head`; then `rvm install 1.9.3`

Comment: For 'brew install autoconf automake'; both already installed. Then did 'brew install https://raw.github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-dupes/master/apple-gcc42.rb'; it installed successfully. Ran 'rvm get head'; installed successfully. Then ran 'rvm install 1.9.3'; got notification that I needed to install libska for ruby 1.9.3. Problem is that libska is already installed. Is it installed in wrong directory?

Answer (score 1):

This has detailed instructions on exactly what you need to do.

[RVM keeps setting up ruby 1.8.7 instead of the latest version 1.9 in MAC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14012963/rvm-keeps-setting-up-ruby-1-8-7-instead-of-the-latest-version-1-9-in-mac/14016321#14016321)