# brew install python3 fails

Tags: homebrew, python-3.3

I want install python3.3 with homebrew.

```
brew install python3
```

but fails.Do I need to install Xcode?

```
Warning: A newer Command Line Tools for Xcode release is avaliable
You should install the latest version from: http://connect.apple.com
==> Downloading http://python.org/ftp/python/3.3.0/Python-3.3.0.tar.bz2
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/python3-3.3.0.tar.bz2
==> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.3.0 --enable-ipv6 --datarootdir=/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.3.0/share --datadir=/usr/local/Cellar/python3
==> make
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 562, in module_for_loader_wrapper
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 854, in _load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 988, in get_code
ValueError: unmarshallable object
make: *** [Lib/_sysconfigdata.py] Segmentation fault: 11

READ THIS: https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/troubleshooting

These open issues may also help:
    https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/16848
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is right in the error. Install X-Code and update the command line tools. Here is the related question that answers your question.

[Xcode 4.4 and later install Command Line Tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329243/xcode-4-4-command-line-tools)