# How to add MWPhotoBrowser to iOS project that is using arc

Tags: ios, static, mwphotobrowser

I am trying to add MWPhotoBrowser library to my ios project which uses storyboard and arc. I am getting all sorts of nasty errors. The method proposed in gethub is somewhat not clear.

So if anyone can please show step by step how to add MWPhotobrowser to a project.
Screen shots along with answers would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a Cocoapod for this: See http://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/mwphotobrowser.

If you haven't used it before, it's a package dependancy manager for iOS / Mac Projects. It makes adding libraries to your project much much easier.

EDIT: You'll need to install the Xcode Command Line tools before this'll work (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329243/xcode-4-4-command-line-tools))

Follow the install instructions at:

http://cocoapods.org/

Then in your 'podfile' add the line:

```
pod 'MWPhotoBrowser', '~> 1.0.1'
```

then type

```
pod install
```

It should automagically deal with ARC vs non-ARC for you.

Comment: Thank you Ben. If you have the time i would like to know how to do it without using pods. If you can spare the time tell me how to do it step by step. Thanks

Comment: By the way i had to install xcode command line tools in order to install cocoa pods

Comment: Thanks @MuhammadNasir. I've added that into the steps above.