# c compiler for mac not xcode

Tags: c, compiler-construction, download

I'm trying to compile a simple C program on mac However I can't ever seem to get Xcode to work so I want something else. I also want to check the code for errors while I'm running it anyone got a good idea?

Comment: XCode comes with the `gcc` and `gdb` command line tools which work (mostly) just like their Linux equivalents. Xcode is just a graphical front-end for those tools.

Answer (score 5):

open `Terminal`, `cd` to your source directory,

then type `gcc -Wall yourProgram.c -o YourProgram` and if everything is good, you will be able to execute the program typing `./YourProgram`

Also, if you are just learning C, then do not use IDEs just yet. get used to the terminal and as your experience builds, move to an IDE.]

Also there are tools like `lint` that analyze your code statically. Use gdb and if available, use valgrind as well for runtime debugging. I am not sure if valgrind is available on mac. Have a look at `dtrace` and how to use it.

Comment: Or stick with the command line forever, and ignore the IDE permanently.  ;-)

Comment: @RandyHoward I bet he wants to learn IOS development later on. :-) He might like the IDE more then. Or maybe Cocoa development.

Comment: Xcode installation has changed; it may be necessary to install the command line tools, per [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9329325/298225).