# Clang++ not understanding c++11 in mac terminal

Tags: c++, macos, c++11, terminal, clang++

I am trying to get some c++ code (with c++11) to compile in the mac terminal. I tried

```
clang++ -std=c++11 main.cpp
```

but i get the error

```
error: invalid value 'c++11' in '-std=c++11'
```

My xcode is completely up to date, I am assuming I am doing something wrong in the terminal? The code runs fine in xcode itself, I just cannot get it to run in the terminal.
Any tips would be great!

Comment: Try `-std=c++0x`

Comment: `-std=c++11` should work with recent clang versions though. Have you updated the command line tools (needs to be done manually), see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329243/xcode-4-4-command-line-tools

Comment: Yep, you need to update. If it doesn't accept `c++11` it's ooold. (You might want to check with the `-v` flag.)

Answer (score 1):

As Andy has already said, your compiler only accepts `-std=c++0x`. It`s probably quite old.

[ Answering only to remove the question from unanswered question queue ]

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure about this but in my experience, being up-to-date in Xcode might not mean that you are up-to-date in clang too, i had problem while trying to compile a c++ code using g++ on mac osx mountain lion. my xcode was latest but gcc was old (4.2.1). i had to install latest version of gcc from http://hpc.sourceforge.net (4.8.1). now it works. i use `g++ -std=c++11` for compiling.