# Xcode 4.6.2 not getting downloaded from mac app store

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, xcode4, download

I have MAC OSX 10.7.4 and I want to download Xcode 4.6.2, but in the mac app store, when I click on `"View in mac app store"`, it opens a dialog box to choose an application and on selecting xcode, nothing happens.

Similarly, I also tried downloading from `devloper.apple.com/xcode`, but on clicking on `"Download"` link, it is redirecting to same page.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Even i tried the same for long. Finally i downloaded from other links(non-official)

Comment: which link? can u tell me

Comment: google for xcode4.6 download.... you will find few

Answer (score 0):

The same thing happened to me yesterday, on a brand new iMac with 10.8.3,
but after re-registration worked today ?!
(The main dialog was mainly English but with a paragraph in German (I live in Gemany),
maybe a mixup between German and US app stores ?)

[xcode-4-4-command-line-tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329243/xcode-4-4-command-line-tools)
has several answers to the same question. Some are out of date;
login [developer.apple.com/downloads](http://developer.apple.com/downloads/)
seems to be the preferred method ... today.

Answer (score 0):

I have OSX10.8.3, just installed from the app store. Then I asked the app store to update Xcode to 4.6.2.   After about 5 minutes of downloading, it now says "installing". But the estimate to completion is constantly changing from "less than a minute" to "5 minutes" to "16 minutes"  and back to "7 minutes"and everything in between.  This has been going on about 10 minutes.  WTH is it doing during "installation" that could possibly be this variable???  Moreover, it is extremely difficult to tell from the little blue progress bar whether it is getting any closer to completion or not.