# Error when upgrading to Ruby2.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, homebrew, ruby-2.0

Basically, when trying to install Ruby2.0 following these instructions: http://architects.dzone.com/articles/upgrading-ruby-20-mountain I've hit a brick wall.

On this step specifically: "rvm install 2.0.0"

I get the following error:

```
Error running 'env LDFLAGS=-L/opt/sm/pkg/active/lib CFLAGS=-I/opt/sm/pkg/active/include CPATH=/opt/sm/pkg/active/include ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195 --with-opt-dir=/opt/sm/pkg/active --disable-install-doc --without-tcl --without-tk --enable-shared',
please read /usr/local/rvm/log/ruby-2.0.0-p195/1370731952_configure.log
There has been an error while running configure. Halting the installation.
```

When following the command prompt instruction to read "/usr/local/rvm/log/ruby-2.0.0-p195/1370731952_configure.log"

#### configure.log file:

```
[2013-06-08 18:52:32] ./configure
current path: /usr/local/rvm/src/ruby-2.0.0-p195
command(9): env LDFLAGS=-L/opt/sm/pkg/active/lib CFLAGS=-I/opt/sm/pkg/active/include CPATH=/opt/sm/pkg/active/include ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195 --with-opt-dir=/opt/sm/pkg/active --disable-install-doc --without-tcl --without-tk --enable-shared
configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --without-tcl, --without-tk
checking build system type... x86_64-apple-darwin12.3.0
checking host system type... x86_64-apple-darwin12.3.0
checking target system type... x86_64-apple-darwin12.3.0
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/usr/local/rvm/src/ruby-2.0.0-p195':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

#### Please advise

Comment: Does the `config.log` file (mentioned at bottom) tell you anything about why the C compiler couldn't create an executable?

Comment: Do you have a C compiler installed?

Comment: Hm..presumably I don't have C compiler installed? I thought that it ships with OSX but I may be wrong.

Comment: Just checked, I do indeed have the command tools including C compiler installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the key error message is `configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables`.  Did you find and look at `config.log` (different than `configure.log`)?  Double-check that you have installed not just [Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/) but the [command line tools](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9329325/712765) as well.

Comment: Thanks, I've just checked my XCode preferences/downloads and command line tools are listed as installed. So that isn't the issue in this case, not quite sure what is to be honest. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you find and look at config.log (different than configure.log)? What did it say?

Comment: Got it working - not sure how..but it works now heh. I'll accept your answer!