# Why can't RVM find compiler and 'make' tool after installing XCode?

Tags: ios, ruby, xcode, macos

I installed RVM on OS X 10.8.3. The command `rvm -v` works but there was one error when I tried to execute the following code:

```
\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --rails # Or, --ruby=2.0.0-p195
```

Here is the error:

```
rvm 1.20.13 (stable) by Wayne E. Seguin , Michal Papis  [https://rvm.io/]

Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: osx/10.8/x86_64/ruby-2.0.0-p195.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Installing requirements for osx, might require sudo password.

    Can not find compiler and 'make' tool - make sure Xcode and/or Command Line Tools are installed.
```

I even tried  `rvm install 1.9.2` but the same error showed up. I also installed Xcode with no luck.

Comment: Well, did you install the Command Line Tools within Xcode? If not, see the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329243/xcode-4-4-command-line-tools) for instructions...

Comment: Yeah, after installing Xcode you have to install Command Line Tools from Xcode.

Comment: @WowBow No worries... I might repost that comment as an answer since it looks like it answered your question.

Comment: Voted and marked as the answer!!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It looks like you have installed Xcode, but not the command line tools that RVM requires to build Ruby and other components (`make`, `gcc`, etc)

Here are some instructions (taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329243/xcode-4-4-command-line-tools)):

> Xcode includes a new "Downloads" preference pane to install optional
>   components such as command line tools, and previous iOS Simulators. 
>   To open this pane click the "Xcode" button in the top left of the
>   screen near the Apple logo, then click "Preferences", then click
>   "Downloads".
>
> [image: screenshot of downloads pane]

Then install the 'Command Line Tools' bundle by clicking the <kbd>Install</kbd> button to the right of it.

Answer (score 4):

For Xcode 5 it's

`Xcode -> Preferences -> Download -> Command Line Tools`