# json error creating a rails app in rails 4.0.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-4

When I am creating a new app in rails 4.0.0 using rvm 1.21.3, I am getting following error

```
$rails_projects MacBook$ rails new rails4app

create
create  README.rdoc
create  Rakefile
create  config.ru
create  .gitignore
create  Gemfile
create  app
create  app/assets/javascripts/application.js
create  app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
create  app/controllers/application_controller.rb
create  app/helpers/application_helper.rb
create  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
create  app/assets/images/.keep
create  app/mailers/.keep
create  app/models/.keep
create  app/controllers/concerns/.keep
create  app/models/concerns/.keep
create  bin
create  bin/bundle
create  bin/rails
create  bin/rake
create  config
create  config/routes.rb
create  config/application.rb
create  config/environment.rb
create  config/environments
create  config/environments/development.rb
create  config/environments/production.rb
create  config/environments/test.rb
create  config/initializers
create  config/initializers/backtrace_silencers.rb
create  config/initializers/filter_parameter_logging.rb
create  config/initializers/inflections.rb
create  config/initializers/mime_types.rb
create  config/initializers/secret_token.rb
create  config/initializers/session_store.rb
create  config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb
create  config/locales
create  config/locales/en.yml
create  config/boot.rb
create  config/database.yml
create  db
create  db/seeds.rb
create  lib
create  lib/tasks
create  lib/tasks/.keep
create  lib/assets
create  lib/assets/.keep
create  log
create  log/.keep
create  public
create  public/404.html
create  public/422.html
create  public/500.html
create  public/favicon.ico
create  public/robots.txt
create  test/fixtures
create  test/fixtures/.keep
create  test/controllers
create  test/controllers/.keep
create  test/mailers
create  test/mailers/.keep
create  test/models
create  test/models/.keep
create  test/helpers
create  test/helpers/.keep
create  test/integration
create  test/integration/.keep
create  test/test_helper.rb
create  tmp/cache
create  tmp/cache/assets
create  vendor/assets/javascripts
create  vendor/assets/javascripts/.keep
create  vendor/assets/stylesheets
create  vendor/assets/stylesheets/.keep
   run  bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..........
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
Using rake (10.1.0)
Using i18n (0.6.4)
Installing minitest (4.7.5)
Using multi_json (1.7.7)
Using atomic (1.1.10)
Using thread_safe (0.1.0)
Using tzinfo (0.3.37)
Using activesupport (4.0.0)
Using builder (3.1.4)
Using erubis (2.7.0)
Using rack (1.5.2)
Using rack-test (0.6.2)
Using actionpack (4.0.0)
Using mime-types (1.23)
Using polyglot (0.3.3)
Using treetop (1.4.14)
Using mail (2.5.4)
Using actionmailer (4.0.0)
Using activemodel (4.0.0)
Using activerecord-deprecated_finders (1.0.3)
Using arel (4.0.0)
Using activerecord (4.0.0)
Using bundler (1.3.5)
Installing coffee-script-source (1.6.2)
Installing execjs (1.4.0)
Installing coffee-script (2.2.0)
Using thor (0.18.1)
Using railties (4.0.0)
Installing coffee-rails (4.0.0)
Using hike (1.2.3)
Installing jbuilder (1.4.2)
Installing jquery-rails (3.0.1)
Installing json (1.8.0)
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

 Users/MacBook/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby extconf.rb
creating Makefile
make
compiling generator.c
linking shared-object json/ext/generator.bundle
make install
/usr/bin/install -c -m 0755 generator.bundle /Users/MacBook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/json-1.8.0/lib/Users/MacBook/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-darwin11.4.2/json/ext
install: /Users/MacBook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/json-1.8.0/lib/Users/MacBook/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-darwin11.4.2/json/ext: No such file or directory
make: *** [install-so] Error 71
Gem files will remain installed in /Users/MacBook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/json-1.8.0 for inspection.

Results logged to /Users/MacBook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/json-1.8.0/ext/json/ext/generator/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing json (1.8.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install json -v '1.8.0'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Comment: Have you installed the [Xcode command line tools][1]?


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329243/xcode-4-4-command-line-tools

Answer (score 0):

Did you try 'bundle install' . It will install all the missing gems . The error is occurring primarily beacuse some gems are missing :)

Comment: AFAIK, `rails new` automatically runs `bundle install`

Comment: Yes , but when it lists that 'so and so' gems are missing , it points out that either it was missed during bundle or there is some version incompatibility .Add that gem to your gemfile and run 'bundle install' again .

Comment: I had to uninstall and then reinstall the entire rvm and rails 4.0.0. That fixed my problem.