# Getting Warning while installing flink on MacBook "There is no C compiler on your system"

Tags: macos, gcc, apt-get, cc, fink

To get support I am installing [fink](http://fink.thetis.ig42.org/download/srcdist.php) on my MacBook Pro. After execute bootstrap script I am getting following error log

```
Checking package... looks good (fink-0.35.1).
Checking system... i386-apple-darwin12.4.0
This system is supported and tested.
Distribution: 10.8
Architecture: x86_64
Checking cc... not found.
ERROR: There is no C compiler on your system. Make sure that the Developer
Tools are installed.
```

I didn't find gcc in /usr/bin/ directory.

After reading [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/index.html), I am guessing x-code provide default support for gcc compiler.

any one have idea what I should to get support of **fink** or if have any other way to get support of **apt-get**.

Comment: XCode does include gcc but it is in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin (use `xcode-select -print-path` to get the part of the path before /usr/bin)

Comment: how can I use it to solve mentioned issue?

Comment: Install XCode and then add the extra directory to the path. Hopefully the fink install should then find the C compiler.

Comment: using mention command I am getting path "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer", sorry but where I need to add this path?

Comment: You need to add it to the command search path in the PATH shell variable. You could do this by adding `export PATH="$PATH:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin"` to your .bash_profile

Comment: You have to install Command Line Tools _within_ Xcode to get `gcc` and other tools. More info in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329243/xcode-4-4-command-line-tools)

Answer (score 1):

- First, you need to install **Xcode** and its **command line tools** to get the gcc compiler
- Make sure that you have working version of gcc in your `/usr/bin` directory
- Create a symbolic link `cc` from installed `gcc` in `/usr/bin`