# What is required and how to install zucchini framework on Mac OSX?

Tags: ios, macos, gui-test-framework, zucchini

[Zucchini framework](http://www.zucchiniframework.org/) seems a promising candidate for quality assurance of iOS user interfaces.

However, the installation steps provided on [their website](http://www.zucchiniframework.org/) assume that most of the prerequisites already exist OR that one is already familiar with the intricacies of command line.

I would like to know what requires to be installed before I can successfully install and use  zucchini framework on Mac OSX.

Comment: This question is not off-topic in my opinion because zucchini framework is a tool most likely to be used by programmers. And for that kind of questions please see here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/130246/150789

Comment: Also quoting from [what is on-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): "software tools commonly used by programmers"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Requirements

[Zucchini framework](http://www.zucchiniframework.org/) has the following requirements:

- Ruby >= 1.9.3
- Xcode >= 4.2 (for this installation process we require Xcode >= 4.6.2)
- Xcode command line tools
- Nodejs
- Coffee script (node module)

### How to install

1. [Install Homebrew](http://brew.sh/)

   `$> ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"`
2. Update Homebrew

   `$> brew update`
3. Install imagemagick and [nodejs](http://dreamerslab.com/blog/en/how-to-setup-a-node-js-development-environment-on-mac-osx-lion/)

   `$> brew install imagemagick node`
4. Install coffee script module for nodejs

   i. Install coffee script

   `$> npm install coffee-script`

   ii. Add coffee bin to your PATH environment variable

   `$> cd ~`

   `$> sudo vim .bash_profile`

   - Press `i`, to switch into *insert mode* then add following line
   - `PATH=$PATH:$HOME/node_modules/coffee-script/bin`
   - Press `:w` to save and
   - Press `:q` to quit vim
   - Now relaunch the terminal.

   iii. Verify that coffee script is successfully installed.

   - At the prompt

     $> coffee
   - To exit from coffee script type following at the `coffee>` prompt:

     process.exit()
5. [Install command line tools for Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9329325/365188)
6. [Install and/or update ruby](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ruby/how-to-install-ruby-on-a-mac/) (if its less than 1.9.3)

   i.  ruby is installed on Mac OSX by default, verify using the following command:

   `$> ruby -v`

   ii. Install rvm (Ruby version manager)

   `$> \curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --rails
   --autolibs=enabled`

   iii. Add rvm bin directory to path variable
   `$> sudo vim .bash_profile`

   - Insert the following line, save and quit
     `[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"`
   - Relaunch the terminal.

   iv. Update ruby to 1.9.3 or later

   `$> rvm install 1.9.3`
7. [Install zucchini](http://www.zucchiniframework.org/)

   `$> gem install zucchini-ios`

NOTE: I have included the reference for each step from where I got help during installation.